# Inline function versus macro

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, macros, inline

I'm working on an iOS app using C and Objective-C, and I want to write a very small piece of code that will be executed thousands of times from more than one place. Is it safe to make this an `inline` function and be sure that it will always be expanded (I won't ever be taking its address) or should I make it a macro? The code is small and it will be executed very frequently, so I'd like to make sure I won't end up with thousands of function calls for it, but still I'd like the type safety of the function approach if possible...

Comment: Yes - use an inline function - it's just as efficient as a macro and a lot more robust.

Comment: @PaulR, so I can be assured that it will never be called as a function? From what I understand, `inline` is just a hint, and the compiler can choose to ignore it.

Comment: With gcc *et al* you can use `__attribute__ ((always_inline))` to force inlining, but this shouldn't be necessary if it's just a small function.

Comment: Or use `gcc -Winline` to alert you if it can't be inlined.  (Though it sounds like OP isn't using gcc.)

Comment: Won't most sensible compilers do this automatically as one of the speed optimisations?  Also inline is not a guarantee but a hint to many compilers

Comment: Also: I suggest you profile your code before you spend very much time worrying about line-level optimizations.  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be sure that a function is inlined, make it "extern inline" (this is a GNU-C feature). Such functions are only used for inlining; the compiler will never generate a "real" function for it. Thus, if the inlining fails, you should be getting linker errors. I assume clang has "inherited" this feature.

In general, always use inline instead of macros, if possible. There's a reason why many C-compilers had it for ages, and C++ finally added it as a core feature; it makes things a lot safer and reliable to use. There are still things that need macros, but those are few and far between.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use an inline function over a macro.

The performance will be identical to a macro (the code is inline, after all) and you'll get type safety as well.

N.B., this assumes that your function is simple enough for the compiler to inline.  gcc's `-Winline` option warns if this isn't the case; not sure what flags do the same on your platform.

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571392/pros-and-cons-of-different-macro-function-inline-methods-in-c) for cases when you might prefer a macro (e.g., deferred evaluation)--but based on your question it sounds like inline function is the clear choice.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I understand a compiler can only inline functions which are in the same source file.  If your inline function is in file A and you're trying to use it elsewhere, it cannot be inlined, *unless* the *linker* does link-time optimization.

This is because the compiler only compiles one C file at a time into one object file.  It cannot *obtain* the inlined function from another object file, because firstly, it may not yet have been compiled and secondly, it wouldn't know which object file to look for anyway.

Comment: That's not really a header file; it's a global C file.