# Returning an object from a member function of the same class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I came across the following program:

```
class Counter { 
 protected:         
  unsigned int count;  

 public:  
  Counter(): count(0) {}   
  Counter(int c): count(c) {}   
  unsigned int get_count() { return count; }  
  Counter operator++() { return Counter(++count); }  
};
```

What does the last member function do (`Counter(++count)`)?

Answer (score 6):

I think you wanted to implement `operator++` for your class, and that should be implemented as:

```
Counter & operator++()
{
   ++count;
   return *this;
}
```

Now the question is what does it do? It does pre-increment. Now you can write `++counter` and that will invoke the above operator overload, and which internally will increment the variable `count` by 1.

Example :

```
Counter counter(1);
++counter;
std::cout << counter.get_count() << std::endl;
++(++counter);
std::cout << counter.get_count() << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
2
4
```

**What your original code does?**

If you try to run the above code using your original implementation of `operator++`, it will print the following :

```
2
3
```

That is because you're creating another temporary object which you're returning, which when you write `++(++counter)` the outer pre-increment will increment the temporary. So the outer pre-increment will not change the value of `counter.count`.

Even if you write `++(++(++(++counter)))`, its equivalent to just `++counter`.

Compare the output here:

- http://www.ideone.com/xRXVq  (your original code)
- http://www.ideone.com/xciWC  (my code)

Note `++(++counter)` [does NOT invoke undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded).

Answer (score 3):

The last function is an overloaded operator. Specifically in the prefix increment operator. It lets you use the prefix ++ operator on objects of that class. For example:

```
  Counter counter;
  ++counter;
  // note this is not implemented
  counter++;
```

This line

```
  Counter(++count)
```

constructs a new Counter object by first incrementing the current instances count then by using the constructor

```
   Counter(int c)
```

The result of the prefix increment, is therefore, a different instance (an incremented copy) then what prefix increment was called on.