# why ++++i regular but i++++ not regular in C++?

Tags: c++

When I use `i++++` give compile error :

```
for (int i=1;i<=10;i++++) {} //a.cpp:63: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

or

```
int i = 0;
i++++; // a.cpp:65: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

but when I use `++++i` is working. Anybody explain me why `++++i` regular but `i++++` not regular?

Thanks.

Comment: ++++i is equivalent to (i=(i+=1)+1) but that doesn't help any.

Comment: `i+=2`saves you one character, and it works. Try that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since type of `x` is built-in primitive type, both expressions invoke **undefined behaviour**, as both attempt to modify the *same* object twice between two sequence points.

**Don't do either of them.**

Read this FAQ :

[Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

---

However if the type of `x` is a user-defined type and you've overloaded `operator++` for both expressions, then both would be **well-defined**.

For this, see this topic to know the explanation and details:

[Undefined behavior and sequence points reloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded)

Comment: Wait, why is the preincrement one UB?

Comment: @Xeo: both attempt to modify the object twice between two sequence points

Comment: Isn't `++++x` implemented as `x.operator++().operator++()` and as such not UB?

Comment: @Xeo: `x` is not user-defined type!

Comment: Well, no reason not to implement it as that for primitive types. :P But really, the two increments are not sequenced?

Comment: @Xeo: Are you trying to say that `operator++` can be implemented for primitive types as well? If so, then no, you cannot.

Comment: @Nawaz: Nono, just that the compiler devs could've done it that way. But it seems I'm wrong after all, no sequencing between the two increments on primitive types.

Comment: `Since type of x is built-in primitive type, both expressions invoke undefined behaviour`.

How does the expression `i++++` invoke UB? Its clearly ill-formed. If a compiler doesn't issue diagnostic for `i++++` its clearly broken.

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav: I think the question has been changed.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard says in section 5.2.6 that the result of i++ is a modifiable lvalue, and in 5.3.2 that the result of ++i is a modifiable lvalue.  This can help explain why i++++ and ++++i aren't required to generate diagnostics and can appear to work sometimes.

However, ++++i modifies i twice between the previous and next sequence points, so the result is still going to be undefined behaviour.  ++++i is allowed to work but it doesn't have to.

Luckily for you, your compiler diagnosed i++++.

Comment: Since I only have access to the C++0x FDIS, did this change? Because 5.2.6 of the FDIS says that the result of `i++` is a (p)rvalue and only talks about the operand (`i`) as being a modifiable lvalue.

Comment: I have the version dated 2003.  C99 does the same thing but with less wording.  If it changed the change must have been some time ago.

Comment: Okay, so `i++++` should be valid (but UB) in C++98/03, but is definitly invalid in C++0x/11.

Comment: For your information,
5.2.6 in the final draft of current standard [here](http://www.kuzbass.ru:8086/docs/isocpp/expr.html)
states _The result is an rvalue_.

Comment: n3290 says that the result of i++ (i being primitive type) is a prvalue. So your answer is flawed!

Answer (score 5):

Because the operators' conceptual "signatures" are:

```
​T& operator ++(T& a);​     // pre
​T operator ++(T& a, int);​ // post
                          // note the int is solely to distinguish the two
```

One returns a reference (an lvalue), and the other does not. Both, however, take a reference as their argument, so the one that returns a reference (`++i`) can be chained, and the one that does not (`i++`) cannot.

Note that, as [@Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987482/why-i-regular-but-i-not-regular-in-c/5987491#5987491) said, the one that works invokes undefined behavior, as would the one that doesn't work in the hypothetical even that it did.

Comment: The *type* in the question is built-in type. So `operator++` doesn't come into the picture.

Comment: @Nawaz - I was using that for illustrative purposes. I'm aware that built-in types don't use `operator++` for anything, but seeing the signatures helps understand the problem.

Comment: If built-in types don't have `operator++`, then how come it can explain the problem?  If the object of illustration is itself wrong, then how can it illustrate anything correctly?

Answer (score 3):

As some say, `++++i` is accepted by your compiler, but when it's evaluated, it produces undefined behavior in C++03.

Note that simply saying `sizeof(++++i)` is fine, because nothing is evaluated. Saying `++++i` is fine in C++11 even if it's evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this from the "what you want to do" view: there is no point to calling `i++++` to start with, because `i++` does *not* return a reference to the incremented `i` variable, but the value `i` had *before* it was incremented. So `i++++` would essentially do this:

1. Copy `i` to a temporary variable `t`
2. Increment `i`
3. Copy `t` to a temporary variable `u`
4. Increment `t`
5. Throw away both `t` and `u`

So all that remains would be one increment of `i`.

On the other hand, `++++i` does simply

1. Increment `i`
2. Increment `i`, again

and that can indeed be useful, not so much in an integer type but certainly when `i` is a non-random-access iterator, because then you can't rely on `i+=2`.