# Retrieving flags in c++ streams

Tags: c++, stream, iostream, flags

How can i make use of flags in c++ streams? I know of `ios_base::flags()`, but when i `cout` them or compare them, they dont change values even with a new flag. a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     cout << cout.flags() << endl;//4098
     cout << std::hex << cout.flags() << endl;// 0x1002
     return 0;
}
```

doesnt change the outputted default value (at least for me) of 4098.

my ultimate goal is to compare the stream to flags to see which are set, **NOT TO SET NEW ONES**. can anyone show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: I believe this is our old friend [Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded) again.  Can someone smart concur?

Comment: i am not asking why this is happening. i am asking about how to compare flags in cout so that i can use the comparisons in conditions

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: It's not undefined behavior; see my answer.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: But it is unspecified, right?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Yes, and remember unspecified means the implementation doesn't have to either document the behavior or be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

With this code:

```
cout << std::hex << cout.flags() << endl;
```

The compiler is allowed to evaluate it in this order:

```
ios_base::fmtflags f = cout.flags();  // store value before applying std::hex
cout << hex;
cout << f;
cout << endl;
```

So you're not guaranteed to "see" flag changes this way.  However, it is not Undefined Behavior.

The flags are a "bitmask type", which is defined to have certain properties – the actual type used is implementation-defined, but integers, enums, and std::bitsets are possibilities.  You can use the normal bit-manipulation operators: ^, &, |, and ~:

```
bool is_hex(std::ios_base &s) {
  return (s.flags() & s.basefield) == s.hex;
}
// is_oct is identical, except with s.oct

// Nothing set in basefield means "determine base from input" for istreams,
// and ostreams use base 10.  This makes is_dec harder to write.

bool is_anybase(std::istream &s) {
  return (s.flags() & s.basefield) == 0;
}

bool is_dec(std::istream &s) {
  std::ios_base::fmtflags base = s.flags() & s.basefield;
  return base == dec;
}
bool is_dec(std::ostream &s) {
  std::ios_base::fmtflags base = s.flags() & s.basefield;
  return (base == dec) || (base == 0);
}
// Purposeful overload ambiguity on std::iostream.
// In 0x, we could write:
bool is_dec(std::iostream &s) = delete;
```

For an example, this is how std::hex works:

```
std::ios_base& hex(std::ios_base &s) {
  s.setf(s.hex, s.basefield);
  return s;
}
```

Where setf does:

```
ios_base::fmtflags fmtflags = s.hex;    // first parameter
ios_base::fmtflags mask = s.basefield;  // second parameter
s.flags((s.flags() & ~mask) | (fmtflags & mask));
```

Comment: I think the function only works if *only* the hexflag is set.

Comment: @Xeo: That's right, my is_hex gives true if only hex is set, which is how streams work (using the num_get/put facets).

Comment: My bad, I didn't exactly know what `basefield` is. :) I thought it's how all the flags are set at default...

Comment: @Xeo there is no hexflag.  Unlike most of the values in `fmtflags`, `hex` is a value in a multibit (at least 2) field.