# Performance difference between using int a=a+1 and a++ in Java

Tags: java, performance, post-increment

Is there any performance difference between using `int a=a+1` and `a++` in `Java`?

If so which is better and why? Could you briefly explain me to understand this?

Comment: concidering micro-optimizations: always do what is more readable, let the compiler optimize for you. Code is for programmers, optimizations are for compilers.

Comment: asking this question cost's you more time than the runtime advantage of the faster (if there is any) solution.

Comment: @Bernhard: I just wanted to know whether there is any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the generated bytecode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;
    int z = 1;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    x = x + 1;
    y++;
    ++z;
    a += 1;
    b += 2;
}
```

generates (use `javap -c classname`)

```
0:   iconst_1
1:   istore_1
2:   iconst_1
3:   istore_2
4:   iconst_1
5:   istore_3
6:   iconst_1
7:   istore  4
9:   iconst_1
10:  istore  5
12:  iload_1
13:  iconst_1
14:  iadd
15:  istore_1
16:  iinc    2, 1
19:  iinc    3, 1
22:  iinc    4, 1
25:  iinc    5, 2
28:  return
```

So using (jdk1.6.0_18):

```
x = x + 1
```

creates

```
12:  iload_1
13:  iconst_1
14:  iadd
15:  istore_1
```

whereas

```
y++;
++z;
a += 1;
```

all result in

```
iinc
```

However, doing a rough performance test on my laptop resulted in next to no difference in the runtime between the two (sometimes ++x was quicker, sometimes x=x+1 was quicker), so I wouldn't worry about the performance implications.

Comment: And the lesson you should learn from this is that you cannot infer Java performance by counting bytecodes!  (Not even if you run with `java -int ...` to turn of JIT compilation.)

Answer (score 15):

First of all, the Java Language Specification doesn't say anything about timing. But assuming we're using a typical compiler such as Suns javac we see that all of the above examples (`a++`, `++a`, `a += 1`, `a = a + 1`) could either be compiled into something like:

- `iinc` instruction, working on variables:

  ```
  iload_<variable>
  iinc <variable>, 1
  istore_<variable>
  ```
- `iadd` instuction, using the stack (here using variable `1` as a the storage):

  ```
  iload_1
  iconst_1
  iadd
  istore_1
  ```

It's up to the compiler to choose the best possible way to compile them. E.g. there is **no difference** between them. And it shouldn't be any difference between the statements - they all express the same thing - adding one to a number.

That beeing said, both the `iinc` and the `iadd` version can be compiled using the JIT to something fast and platform dependent, and in the end I would assume that a normal runtime compiles both versions into the same assembler code.

---

With my compiler, *jdk1.6.0_20* the "increment" methods even uses the same instruction.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 0;

        a = a + 1;
        a += 1;
        a++;
        ++a;
    }
}
```

This is the disassembly:

```
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class Test extends java.lang.Object{
public Test();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #8; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iinc    1, 1   // a = a + 1;
   5:   iinc    1, 1   // a += 1;
   8:   iinc    1, 1   // a++;
   11:  iinc    1, 1   // ++a;
   14:  return

}
```

Comment: can you pls. add details for `++a` also?

Comment: @Azodious: Depends on the case, if I just add `++a;` to the above statements it will just convert it to an another `iinc 1, 1`. However in a more complex scenario the ordering of the instructions will is different (see this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5413548/java-prefix-postfix-of-increment-decrement-operators-need-help-with-example)).

Comment: I think at "iinc instruction, working on variables" there is a mistake. `iinc` does not need `iload` and `istore` (?)

Answer (score 2):

No, there won't be any noticeable difference. Use what you find the most readable (which is `a++`, normally).

First rule of code optimization: don't.

Comment: I didnt downvote but actually i dont agree with your point. From a clean code perspective `a+=1` is at least from my perspective a more solid approach both for readability and fault tolerance. Did you ever evaluate `a+++b`(in Java and C++) ?  The only argument for a++ was the different processor instruction but this is nowerdays optimized by the JVM.

Comment: we're not discussing a+++b here. We're discussing a++, which is the instruction meaning "*increment a*". It's readable by any Java developer, and there is no understandability problem with this instruction.

Comment: Thats exactly the point everybody should understand it. But it is not saying "increment a". The meaning of a++ is "increment a after the current expression"

Comment: Not when the expression used is just `a++`. In this case, it doesn't matter if the increment is done before or after the assignment: there is no assignment. That was the question of the OP: `a = a + 1` or `a++`?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should optimize and there should be no difference at all.
But keep in mind that prefix increment operator **may be** (it depends by the compiler) faster than the postfix equivalent (in C++ and C# also):

`++a` faster than `a++` because the postfix operator must create a temporary variable.. think about their implementation:

prefix:

```
a = a + 1;
return a;
```

postfix:

```
int tmp = a;
a = a + 1;
return tmp;
```

Comment: nop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c

Comment: as I said: **may be**. not all compilers optimize that way though.

Comment: @vulkanino: must read for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded

Answer (score 0):

a++ is much faster. It converts to INC command of assembler.But I think JVM will optimize a=a+1 so you don't need to care about that.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same, and nowadays with compiler optimization should not be aware of that stuff, to increase your performance check other bigger issues like allocs :)