# Difference between a+=b and a=a+b in Java

Tags: java, types, operators

I've been told that there are differences between a+=b; and a=a+b; which can result in only one of those being legal depending on the type declerations.

Does anyone have an example of this?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957085/why-are-arithmetic-assignment-operators-more-efficient) might help you

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for e.g. declaring 'a' as a byte and 'b' as an int will result in a=a+b being illegal and a+=b being legal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is basically no difference, however **there is a subtle difference.**

The arithmetic assignment operators do an implicit cast. e.g.

```
byte a = 1;
int b = 2;

a += b; // compiles
a = a + b; // doesn't compile as a byte + int = int
a = (byte) (a + b); // compiles as this is the same as +=
```

For more weird examples.

```
int a = 5;
a += 1.5f;
// a == 6

char ch = '0'; // (char) 49
ch *= 1.1;     // ch = '4';

long l = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
l += 0.0f;   // i = (long ) ((long ) l + 0.0f)
// i == Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1L; WTF!?
// l is no longer Integer.MAX_VALUE due to rounding error.
```

Answer (score 1):

The JLS (section [15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)) says:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.

The presence of the type-cast means that there are a couple of edge cases where `a = a op b` means something different to `a op= b`.

See Peter Lawrey's answer for one example.  It is when `a` is a `byte` and `b` is an `int` and the "op" is `+`.   The "gotcha" is `a + b` produces an `int`, which then can't be assigned to `a` ... without a typecast.

The same scenario applies with other types for `a` and `b` and for other arithmentic and bitwise operators.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;   
a=a+b; // 30

a+=b; // 30

System.out.println(a);
```

Both will give the same answer.