# What languages don't define execution order for multi-statement for statements?

Tags: syntax, for-loop

Some C-like languages allow multiple statements in the update part of a `for` statement, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++, butter--, syrup--, pancakesDevoured++)
```

Java explicitly defines the order for such statements in [JLS 14.14.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1.2) and 15.8.3 of ECMA-334 (C#) says "the expressions of the for-iterator, if any, are evaluated in 
sequence" which I'm reading as left-to-right.

What languages, if any, allow multiple statements in the update part of a `for` loop but either don't define an ordering for such statements or use an order other than left to right?

edit: removed the `C` tag since that started a sequence point discussion and [there's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) [plenty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) [of that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded) already.

Comment: In C that is called the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) and is not exclusive to `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, that's a single expression, not one or more statements, though the distinction isn't super important.

Good old C makes only limited promises about what order expressions like this will be evaluated in. In your example, the order doesn't matter. But consider this expression:

```
a[i++] = i
```

If `i` was 1 before evaluating this expression, should `a[1]` now equal 1 or 2? As I understand the C specification, the behavior of this expression is undefined, meaning that what you get depends on which compiler you use.

---

Thanks to @mizo for a readable reference on [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point), and to @ChrisDodd for pointing out that if you're making simple independent assignments that are separated by the comma operator, C and C++ do fully specify a left-to-right evaluation order.

Comment: Understanding how [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) work is key.