# Pre/Post Increment Operator Output

Tags: c, operator-precedence

```
int i=3;

int k=i++ + ++i;

int j=i++ + ++i + ++i + i++ + i++;  /*is this statement compiler dependent?*/

printf("K=%d j=%d",k,j);
```

and second one is

`j=-i++;`

In this expression which operation is performed first;
both are right to left associative and having same precedence. Actually I want to know the concept of Associativity and Precedence in context of Unary operator using this example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4638364/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points-reloaded

Comment: The second part: postfix operators bind more tightly than prefix. Note that if you write `(-i)++`, that doesn't even compile, because `-i` is an rvalue and you can't apply increment to that.