# Objective-C #define macro evaluation incorrect within if statement

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am confused about why the following `#define` macros are not evaluating as expected when used in the following if statement:

```
#define kOffsetX  2048.0
#define kPositionX (screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0))-10.0

CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
float potentialPosition = 486.86f;
float playersFieldOffset = 1.0;

if ((potentialPosition - kPositionX) * playersFieldOffset > 0.0) {
```

Note that kPositionX evaluates to 470.0. The if statement evaluates to FALSE when clearly 486-470 is greater than zero. However, if I put parenthesis around kPositionX, then the if statement properly evaluates to TRUE.

Why is this happening? Is this an improper way to use a `#define`? If so, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor just replaces all macros by their definition, so

```
potentialPosition - kPositionX
```

is expanded to

```
potentialPosition - (screenSize.width * (2048.0/2048.0))-10.0
```

which, when evaluated at runtime, gives

```
486.86 - 480 - 10  = -3.14 < 0
```

You should always enclose expressions in macros in parentheses:

```
#define kPositionX ((screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0))-10.0)
```

so that the expansion gives

```
potentialPosition - ((screenSize.width * (2048.0/2048.0))-10.0)
```

which is what you expect.

This is (one of the) disadvantages of preprocessor macros. Alternatively, you can
use for example (inline) functions, see  [Inline functions vs Preprocessor macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros)
for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever using #define, make sure to wrap the entire contents of the #define in parentheses.  This will prevent any incorrect order of operations calculations from happening.  So change your #defines to

```
#define kOffsetX  (2048.0)
#define kPositionX ((screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0))-10.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`#define` macros are *literal expressions*! After any arguments are spliced in (and you aren't using any arguments for this macro), the macro is basically inserted directly into the code. So, while you are expecting

`if ((potentialPosition - kPositionX) * playersFieldOffset > 0.0)`

to turn into

`if ((potentialPosition - (answer of kPositionX) * playersFieldOffset > 0.0)`

it actually turns into

`if ((potentialPosition - (screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0)) - 10.0) * playersFieldOffset > 0.0)`

Which evaluates incorrectly. You could solve this by either surrounding the whole macro in parentheses.

`#define kPositionX ((screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0)) - 10.0)`

or, as you said, surrounding kPositionX with parentheses

`if ((potentialPosition - (kPositionX)) * playersFieldOffset > 0.0) {`

Also, as a general rule of good practice, macros are usually written in all capitals, with underscores (_) showing a break between words. #define MACRO_NUMBER_ONE

Answer (score 1):

Macros work by *string substitution*. Your macro `kPositionX` is of the form *(a) - b* so when you use it in the subexpression `(potentialPosition - kPositionX)` the result is:

```
(potentialPosition - (screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0)) - 10.0)
```

in which `10.0` is *subtracted* from `potentialPosition`. Probably you wanted:

```
(potentialPosition - ((screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0)) - 10.0))
```

note the extra parentheses - in which `10.0` is *added* to `potentialPosition`.

You must always remember that macros use string substitution when defining them, and any macro containing an expression should have outer parentheses to avoid problems:

```
#define kPositionX ((screenSize.width * (kOffsetX/2048.0)) - 10.0)
```