# Understanding side effect in #define usage

Tags: c

I am referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros)

> `#define max(a,b) ((a<b)?b:a)`

this will have a some side effect as stated in the answer;

> The side effects appear if you use max(a++,b++) for example (a or b
>   will be incremented twice)

I am not able to understand this side effect; why a or b will be incremented twice when we use max(a++,b++) ?

Comment: Remember that macros are actually text replacement. Expand out the macro and you should see the problem.

Comment: @FredLarson your suggestion indeed helped me. thanks

Comment: Also read  [Sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `max(a++,b++)` in your code like this,

```
x = max(a++,b++);
```

a text replacement happens as

```
x = ((a++<b++)? b++ : a++);
      ^   ^     ^---------Increment if condition is true
      |---|---------Increment
```

So you will be incrementing either `a` or `b` twice...

Comment: There is no parenthesis enclosing `a++` and `b++`.

Comment: The text replacement will actually be `x = ((a++<b++)?b++:a++);`

Comment: @timrau Ya was trying to edit the text, but the browser was stuck. Sorry for the mistake...

Comment: @NikosC. Ya was trying to edit the text, but the browser was stuck. Sorry for the mistake...

Answer (score 1):

`max(a++, b++)` will be expanded as `((a++ < b++) ? b++ : a++)`. While evaluating from the left the expression `(a++ < b++)` get precedence and will increment both `a` and `b`. This is the first increment. Then depending the output of `<` operator, either `a` or `b` will get incremented again (this is the second increment).