# create macro for c++ stream

Tags: c++, macros

I am writing a macro which get std stream as arguments. For example

file.h

```
int enable = 0;
#define MYLOG(hanlde) \
    if (enable==0) { LOG1(handle) } \
    else { LOG2(handle) }
```

file.cpp

```
MYLOG(handle) << "Test log msg";
```

My intended result after preprocessor execution must be

```
LOG1(handle) << "Test log msg"; // if handle = 0
LOG2(handle) << "Test log msg"; // if handle = 1
```

Does this possible with macro in c++. If possible please provide the example.

Comment: The macro does not do much for your intended use. It might as well be a function.

Comment: @RSahu You are right my expectation is possible with function. But i don't want to do function call because it called from lots of places.

Comment: Simple `inline` functions are just as efficient as macros with modern compilers. They are better for other reasons too. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, your version of the MYLOG macro is clearly not going to expand out to valid C++ code.

The following alternative has a better chance of working as intended; however it also depends on what `LOG1` and `LOG2` really is

```
#define MYLOG(handle) (enable == 0 ? LOG1(handle):LOG2(handle))
```

Answer (score 2):

The macro, as presented, will not work. You'll need to use something like:

```
#define MYLOG(hanlde) \
    (enable == 0 ? LOG1(handle) : LOG2(handle))
```

Having said that, you can use an `inline` function that works just as well.

```
inline std::ostream& MYLOG(handle_type handle)
{
    return (enable == 0 ? LOG1(handle) : LOG2(handle))
}
```

Simple `inline` functions are just as efficient as macros with modern compilers. They are better for other reasons too. See [Inline functions vs Preprocessor macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros).