# std::bind not interoperable with lua_call

Tags: c++, c++11, lua

Using the developement libraries for Lua 5.3.5 and gcc 9.2.0 I have encountered a weird compilation issue for the following minimal snippet:

```
#include <functional>

extern "C" {
  #include "lua.h"
  #include "lualib.h"
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;

  auto lua_simple_call = std::bind(lua_call, _1, 0, 0);
}
```

gcc complains: `error: ‘lua_call’ was not declared in this scope`. This issue does not occur when trying to simply call `lua_call` without the use of `std::bind` and it also does not seem to occur for other Lua C functions like `lua_newtable` etc. I would like to know what's causing this and how to circumvent it.

Comment: Isn't `lua_call` a macro or something? What is its definition?

Comment: It is, but I don't see the issue because it simply expands to a call to `lua_callk`.

Comment: In order to understand why it is not possible, you need to read a bit more about the way preprocessing macros work. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros and go deeper. Eventually, you'll find a solution.

Comment: You can wrap it into lambda: `[](lua_State* s){ lua_call(s,0,0); }` or pass pointer to real function of Lua, not macro: `std::bind(lua_callk,_1,0,0,0,0)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As OP mentioned, `lua_call` is a macro which expands to `lua_callk` but this is only half of the truth.

`lua_call` is a **function** macro:

[`github: lua.h`:](https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/9b7987a9d1471ba94764286b28e0998f73deb46a/lua.h#L283)

```
#define lua_call(L,n,r)     lua_callk(L, (n), (r), 0, NULL)
```

and that makes the difference.

So, `lua_call` will expand to `lua_callk` only if used with the right number of arguments.

I made an MCVE to demonstrate this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define lua_call(L, n, r) lua_callk(L, (n), (r))

void lua_callk(void *L, int n, int r)
{
  std::cout << "lua_callk(" << L << ", " << n << ", " << r << ")\n";
}

#define TEST(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  TEST(lua_call(nullptr, 2, 1));
  //TEST(std::cout << "&lua_call: " << &lua_call << '\n');
}
```

Output:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
lua_call(nullptr, 2, 1);
lua_callk(0, 2, 1)
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/121edba28bab1e49)

versus:

```
#include <iostream>

#define lua_call(L, n, r) lua_callk(L, (n), (r))

void lua_callk(void *L, int n, int r)
{
  std::cout << "lua_callk(" << L << ", " << n << ", " << r << ")\n";
}

#define TEST(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  TEST(lua_call(nullptr, 2, 1));
  std::cout << "&lua_call: " << &lua_call << '\n');
}
```

Output:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:15:34: error: 'lua_call' was not declared in this scope
   15 |   std::cout << "&lua_call: " << &lua_call << '\n';
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbaf8102d96fd0b9)

or, to make this even more obvious:

```
//#include <iostream>

#define lua_call(L, n, r) lua_callk(L, (n), (r))

void lua_callk(void *L, int n, int r)
{
  std::cout << "lua_callk(" << L << ", " << n << ", " << r << ")\n";
}

#define TEST(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  TEST(lua_call(nullptr, 2, 1));
  std::cout << "&lua_call: " << &lua_call << '\n';
}
```

with pre-processor-only run:

```
# 1 "main.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "main.cpp"


void lua_callk(void *L, int n, int r)
{
  std::cout << "lua_callk(" << L << ", " << n << ", " << r << ")\n";
}


int main()
{
  std::cout << "lua_call(nullptr, 2, 1)" << ";\n"; lua_callk(nullptr, (2), (1));
  std::cout << "&lua_call: " << &lua_call << '\n';
}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02f5e4b3328a2bdc)

---

The fix is obvious as well (as already mentioned in [Rafix' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635927/stdbind-not-interoperable-with-lua-call/60636382#comment107276595_60635927)):

Just wrap `lua_bind()` into something addressable: a function or lambda.

Comment: I feel very stupid now for not realizing this myself, but this is a great explanation anyways!