# Inline function global scope

Tags: c

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros) inline functions doesn't have to be inlined. So let's say we have code like this:

```
int a = 0;

inline void myFunc(){
    extern int a;
    a = 1;
}

int main(){
    int a = 0;
    myFunc();
}
```

1. Does standard guarantee which `a` variable will be assigned `1`?
2. Are inline function compiled to a certain code before inlining? If so, what if I use `register` keyword for `a` in `main`?

EDIT: the global `int a` doesn't have to be declared in the same .c file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inlining a function does not introduce it into the caller's scope. Identifiers declared within a function (such as `a` in `main` in your example) are not visible from other functions.

So `inline` is irrelevant, and the top-level `a` is the one whose value is changed.