# Can I use __LINE__ or __FILE__ in inline function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, logging

I faced a problem while implementing the logger.

First, I used to `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` with standard C Macro function like below

```
// global.h
..
namespace MyLogger {

class Logger
{
    ..
    void _write(int _level, const char* _file, int _line, const char* _fmt, ...);
};
static Logger    logger;

}; // namespace MyLogger

..

// avoid conflict..
#undef error
#undef trace

#define error(_MESSAGE_, ...) _write(LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, (const char*)__FILE__, (int)__LINE__, (const char*)_MESSAGE_, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define info(_MESSAGE_, ...)  _write(LOG_LEVEL_INFO,  (const char*)__FILE__, (int)__LINE__, (const char*)_MESSAGE_, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define trace(_MESSAGE_, ...) _write(LOG_LEVEL_TRACE, (const char*)__FILE__, (int)__LINE__, (const char*)_MESSAGE_, ##__VA_ARGS__)
..

// main.cpp

using namespace MyLogger;

// using like this
logger.error("- log error");
logger.info("- log info %s", "test 1");
..
```

In fact, it seems to work well.
However, the problem occurred while using openv.

**error** and **trace** seem to conflicted with **error** and **trace** in **opencv**.

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
> [build]  CV_EXPORTS CV_NORETURN void error(int _code, const String& _err, const char* _func, const char* _file, int _line);

So I'm thinking about other methods using inline functions, not macros.

```
// global.h
..
    //void _write(int _level, const char* _file, int _line, const char* _fmt, ...);
    static inline void error(/* Is it possible to toss __LINE__ or __FILE__ ? */);
    static inline void info(/* .. */);
    static inline void trace(/* .. */);
..

// main.cpp
logger::error("- log error");
logger::info("%d %c %f, 1, 'A', '0.1');
```

Can I know the line or file of the location where the log was output through a method other than a macro?

Comment: To bad you can't use C++20 and [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, `inline` functions/methods won't work the same as macro in this context.
Macros are simply text replacements, that's why the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` will give accurate results. Thus **macros are your only choice**; See if you can name them better to avoid conflicts.

However the `inline` functions are systematically compiled subunits. So the line number and the file names will always be same that of those functions where it resides.

Refer: [Inline functions vs Preprocessor macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137575/inline-functions-vs-preprocessor-macros)

### C++20

As suggested in [this useful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73524406/can-i-use-line-or-file-in-inline-function-in-c/73524434#comment129837184_73524406), you may also consider using [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which allows you to avoid the macro trickery via the help of standard library & language features.

Comment: In fact, it was confirmed that __LINE__ or __FILE__ was not working when passed with a fixed factor in the inline function. So is there any other way than using macros?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 stages in which C++ becomes a running program.

1. Preprocessor
2. Compiler
3. Linker

`__LINE__` and `__FILE__` are processed by the preprocessor (stage 1). However, it's the compiler that decides about inlining (stage 2).

Other languages like C# have this in the compiler stage: `[CallerMemberName]`, `[CallerFilePath]` and `[CallerLineNumber]` [[MSDN]](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-6.0) but I am don't think this exists in C++ at the moment.

Comment: Again, there seems to be no choice but to use macros. I think I need to change the name of the macro to avoid conflict. Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#define log_error(_MESSAGE_, ...) \
    logger._write( \
        LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, \
        (const char*)__FILE__, \
        (int)__LINE__, \
        (const char*)_MESSAGE_, \
        ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

There is no much difference (in the sense of typed characters) between `logger.error` and `log_error`. The advantages are, that you use a macro (__FILE__, __LINE__ are utilized as desired) and have your `logger` class used only at one place (via the macro, in case you want to use a different logging mechanism), refactoring should be without any headaches.

Comment: Thank you for the new idea. Similar to your code, we created a new macro by avoiding the "error" keyword.