# When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?

Tags: c++, inline, one-definition-rule, inline-functions

When should I write the keyword `inline` for a function/method in C++?

After seeing some answers, some related questions:

- When should I **not** write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method in C++?
- When will the compiler not know when to make a function/method 'inline'?
- Does it matter if an application is **multithreaded** when one writes 'inline' for a function/method?

Comment: If you define a function in a header you will need to declare it inline. Otherwise you will get linker errors about multiple definitions of the function.

Comment: @Martin:  Unless it's in a class definition, to be picky.

Comment: @David: To be extra picky, that's only because such functions are implicitly marked `inline` (9.3/2).

Comment: Related: [Does it make any sense to use inline keyword with templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10535667/183120)

Comment: Also see [Inline Functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-member-fns.html) in the C++ FAQ. They have a very good treatment of inline.

Comment: @MartinYork well you could avoid linker errors by using `static` even no?

Answer (score 1179, accepted):

Oh man, one of my pet peeves.

`inline` is more like `static` or `extern` than a directive telling the compiler to inline your functions.  `extern`, `static`, `inline` are linkage directives, used almost exclusively by the linker, not the compiler.

It is said that `inline` hints to the compiler that you think the function should be inlined.  That may have been true in 1998, but a decade later the compiler needs no such hints.  Not to mention humans are usually wrong when it comes to optimizing code, so most compilers flat out ignore the 'hint'.

- **`static`** - the variable/function name cannot be used in other translation units.  Linker needs to make sure it doesn't accidentally use a statically defined variable/function from another translation unit.
- **`extern`** - use this variable/function name in this translation unit but don't complain if it isn't defined.  The linker will sort it out and make sure all the code that tried to use some extern symbol has its address.
- **`inline`** - this function will be defined in multiple translation units, don't worry about it.  The linker needs to make sure all translation units use a single instance of the variable/function.

**Note:** Generally, declaring templates `inline` is pointless, as they have the linkage semantics of `inline` already. However, explicit specialization and instantiation of templates [require `inline`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536588/183120) to be used.

---

Specific answers to your questions:

- > When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method in C++?

  Only when you want the function to be defined in a header.  More exactly only when the function's definition can show up in multiple translation units.  It's a good idea to define small (as in one liner) functions in the header file as it gives the compiler more information to work with while optimizing your code.  It also increases compilation time.
- > When should I not write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method in C++?

  Don't add inline just because you think your code will run faster if the compiler inlines it.
- > When will the compiler not know when to make a function/method 'inline'?

  Generally, the compiler will be able to do this better than you.  However, the compiler doesn't have the option to inline code if it doesn't have the function definition.  In maximally optimized code usually all `private` methods are inlined whether you ask for it or not.

  As an aside to prevent inlining in GCC, use `__attribute__(( noinline ))`, and in Visual Studio, use `__declspec(noinline)`.
- > Does it matter if an application is multithreaded when one writes 'inline' for a function/method?

  Multithreading doesn't affect inlining in any way.

Comment: +1 Best description of inline I have seen in ... (forever). I will now rip you off and use this in all my explanations of the inline keyword.

Comment: Does your answer to "When should I not write..." essentially mean, "if you think a function should be inline it shouldn't." Are your saying that we should inline one liners as a rule and not think too much about the rest?

Comment: @Ziggy, what I was trying to say was that compiler inlining and the `inline` keyword are not related.  You've got the right idea though.  As a rule, guessing what would would be improved by inlining is very error prone.  The exception to that rule being one liners.

Comment: This answer confuses me a bit. You say all that about the compiler being able to inline / not inline things better. Then you say that you should put one liners / small functions in the header, and that the compiler can't inline code without the function definition. Aren't these a bit contradictory? Why not just put everything in the cpp file and let the compiler decide?

Comment: The compiler will only inline function calls where the definition is available at the call site.  Leaving all function in the cpp file would limit inlining to that file.  I suggest defining small one liners inline in the .h as the cost to compilation speed is negligible and you're almost guaranteed the compiler will inline the call.  My point about compiler inlining is that it is port of the black art of optimization, at which your compiler is much better than you are.

Comment: Is this answer still true? The idea that compilers pretty much do their own thing when inlining seems to fly in the face of the internet's cumulative knowledge. I like the idea of not inlining any more because of circular dependencies, but I won't tolerate losing performance.

Comment: Whenever I read something to the account of *the internet's cumulative knowledge* I have to think of John Lawton's famous quote: [The irony of the Information Age is that it has given new respectability to uninformed opinion.](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/152506-the-irony-of-the-information-age-is-that-it-has)

Comment: Very nice answers but I still can't get how compiler will be able to inline a function if it doesn't see it's definition. Let's imagine we have main.cpp, func.cpp, func.h. In main we call `func()`. main.cpp is a separate compilation unit so it has no idea about func definition. Another situtation - what happens (yes, it's bad design) if class definition is divided into 2 separate files. Then how will private methods be inlined if compiler sees no their definition anymore?

Comment: "However, the compiler doesn't have the option to inline code if it doesn't have the function definition." Recent linker/compilier can do link time optimization and can inline function later if necessary.

Comment: @deft_code: +1 for clarity in words, but what's confusing is that in the standard §7.1.2/3 footnote says `The inline keyword has no effect on the linkage of a function.`. Am I missing something here.

Comment: @legends2k: linkage here is referring to a symbol can be used outside its compilation unit. This aspect of linking is controlled by `extern` (the default ... usually) and `static`. It is well defined to have a `static inline` or `extern inline` function.

Comment: @Imray, it looks like the official term in the standard is "translation unit". I use the two interchangeably, but that may not be correct. see [What is a translation unit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) for more info.

Comment: msvc also has __declspec(forceinline)

Comment: Your suggestion on using the 'inline' keyword seems over-complicated. I honestly feel like you could completely strip the inline keyword from the language and nothing would change. If you implement it in the header, the compiler will make the decision on its own; regardless of what you tell it.

Comment: @RobertDailey, C++ has no module support yet. The compiler for the most has no idea what a header is. When C++ gets good module support, you'll be correct that much(all?) of `inline`s semantics will not be needed.

Comment: Also this answer seems a bit incorrect since section [7.1.2] in the C++03 standard states `"...The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism..."` So it's not just for scoping (even though I completely agree, the standard does make it pretty clear that it's more than that).

Comment: Ah, the pearls of C++ wisdom and mythology that very few will ever know.  It's like the keyword was named `inline` solely to confuse the masses and keep the true meaning hidden for a select royal few.  "Don't add inline when you think your code will run faster if the compiler inlines it."  -- This was hilarious and very counter-intuitive, and also 100% correct :D

Comment: So why do professionals use FORCEINLINE. As an example, UE4 source code has a lot of inline methods. Why do they let compiler do inlining?

Comment: @deft_code " It's a good idea to define small (as in one liner) functions in the header file" Modern compilers can use Link Time Opmization/Whole Program Optimization, when this is used defining a function in a header file makes no difference regarding inlining.

Comment: @Etienne: Sure it does. Just because the linker can do inlining at lunchtime doesn't necessarily mean it will make the same decision, as the compiler would have. And btw.: GCC's inliner still does consider the inline keyword when making it's decision. It is not difficult to come up with an example, where versions with and without will result in different assembler code.

Comment: "the compiler doesn't have the option to inline code if it doesn't have the function definition", so if you want the compiler to have the option to inline, then you should put it in the header, which means it may be included by multiple compilation units, requiring you to use 'inline'. Alas, have we not come full circle by saying "use 'inline' to allow the compiler to inline"?   (...or maybe I'm just missing it :))

Comment: I have optimized several algorithms by simply adding "inline" where my profiler told me there was a bottle neck. I don't think that all compilers can always outperform human intervention.

This answer is misleading and incomplete. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932311/when-to-use-inline-function-and-when-not-to-use-it

Comment: "so most compilers flat out ignore the 'hint'." This is patently false. At least Clang and GCC use the inline keyword as a hint for inlining: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/inline-hints/

Comment: LLVM will inline functions costing less than 225 or 325 if hinted. For scale a 7 case switch statement "costs" 110, devirtualization saves 100 cost.
So hints do effect the compilers' inlining decisions and more than I thought (naively one would expect up to 50% more inlining if all functions were hinted).
The intent of the ignore statement is to point out that the compiler inlines many functions w/o the hint and ignores complex hinted functions. I'll update the the comment to be more clear.

Comment: I have a different observation. Using inline does make a difference across translation units. Example of two simple get functions in release mode with VS2017: the one with inline specifier gets inlined and the other is just a normal function call. Things become more obscure though using /LTCG or DLL module boundary.

Comment: "only when the function's definition can show up in multiple translation units." is there any use case that you need this one ?

Comment: @Trevor An important one in modern C++ is `constexpr`, which implies `inline`. The compiler can't evaluate a function without actually having it's definition, so you need it to be `inline` as every TU that uses it must have the definition.

Comment: Why does the MS C++ docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=vs-2019 say "The inline and __inline specifiers instruct the compiler to insert a copy of the function body into each place the function is called."  if (now 20 years later), compilers ignore it?

Comment: How did this answer get so many upvotes? It confused me more that I already was

Comment: @deft_code  you said that __" you should use `inline` keyword when the function's definition can show up in multiple translation units__  and `Johannes Schaub - litb` said that in his answer(bottom of this page)  __" If the function is declared in the header and defined in the .cpp file, you should not use the `inline` keyword."__  so I used `inline` keyword while declaring the function in `.h`  header file and I define it in .cpp file but it give error such as `undefined reference` so I feel `johannes Schaub - litb` is correct but I am not sure so can you please put some light on this.

Comment: Although the compiler "can" inline functions in .cpp files automatically with GCC you need to tell it with flags such as -flto ( link-time optimiser )(and compile all source files ( and libraries ) with this flag ) otherwise it won't ( or just for those source files compiled with the flag ).

Comment: Does this also apply to member functions/variables?

Answer (score 120):

I'd like to contribute to all of the great answers in this thread with a convincing example to disperse any remaining misunderstanding.

Given two source files, such as:

- **inline111.cpp:**

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  void bar();

  inline int fun() {
    return 111;
  }

  int main() {
    std::cout << "inline111: fun() = " << fun() << ", &fun = " << (void*) &fun;
    bar();
  }
  ```
- **inline222.cpp:**

  ```
  #include <iostream>

  inline int fun() {
    return 222;
  }

  void bar() {
    std::cout << "inline222: fun() = " << fun() << ", &fun = " << (void*) &fun;
  }
  ```

---

- **Case A:**

  *Compile*:

  ```
  g++ -std=c++11 inline111.cpp inline222.cpp
  ```

  *Output*:

  ```
  inline111: fun() = 111, &fun = 0x4029a0
  inline222: fun() = 111, &fun = 0x4029a0
  ```

  *Discussion*:

  1. Even thou you ought to have identical definitions of your inline
     functions, C++ compiler does not flag it if that is not the case (actually, due to *separate compilation* it has no ways to check it). It is your own duty to ensure this!
  2. Linker does not complain about *One Definition Rule*, as `fun()` is declared as `inline`. However, because **inline111.cpp** is the first translation unit (which actually calls `fun()`) processed by compiler, the compiler instantiates `fun()` upon its *first* call-encounter in **inline111.cpp**. If compiler decides **not** to expand `fun()` upon its call from anywhere else in your program (*e.g.* from **inline222.cpp**), the call to `fun()` will always be linked to its instance produced from **inline111.cpp** (the call to `fun()` inside **inline222.cpp** may also produce an instance in that translation unit, but it will remain unlinked). Indeed, that is evident from the identical `&fun = 0x4029a0` print-outs.
  3. Finally, despite the `inline` suggestion to the compiler to *actually expand* the one-liner `fun()`, it *ignores* your suggestion completely, which is clear because `fun() = 111` in both of the lines.

---

- **Case B:**

  *Compile* *(notice reverse order)*:

  ```
  g++ -std=c++11 inline222.cpp inline111.cpp
  ```

  *Output*:

  ```
  inline111: fun() = 222, &fun = 0x402980
  inline222: fun() = 222, &fun = 0x402980
  ```

  *Discussion*:

  1. This case asserts what have been discussed in **Case A**.
  2. Notice an important point, that if you comment out the actual call to `fun()` in **inline222.cpp** (*e.g.* comment out `cout`-statement in **inline222.cpp** completely) then, despite the compilation order of your translation units, `fun()` will be instantiated upon it's first call encounter in **inline111.cpp**, resulting in print-out for **Case B** as `inline111: fun() = 111, &fun = 0x402980`.

---

- **Case C:**

  *Compile* *(notice -O2)*:

  ```
  g++ -std=c++11 -O2 inline222.cpp inline111.cpp
  ```

  or

  ```
  g++ -std=c++11 -O2 inline111.cpp inline222.cpp
  ```

  *Output*:

  ```
  inline111: fun() = 111, &fun = 0x402900
  inline222: fun() = 222, &fun = 0x402900
  ```

  *Discussion*:

  1. As is [described here](http://jijithchandran.blogspot.de/2013/12/force-inline-functions-in-cgcc.html), `-O2` optimization encourages compiler to *actually expand* the functions that can be inlined (Notice also that `-fno-inline` is *default* without optimization options). As is evident from the outprint here, the `fun()` has actually been *inline expanded* (according to its definition in that *particular* translation unit), resulting in two *different* `fun()` print-outs. Despite this, there is still *only one* globally linked instance of `fun()` (as required by the standard), as is evident from *identical* `&fun` print-out.

Comment: Your answer is an illustrative post of why language makes such `inline` functions to be undefined behavior.

Comment: You ought to also add cases where compiling and linking is separate, with each `.cpp` being its own translation unit. Preferably, add cases for `-flto` enabled/disabled.

Comment: The C++ reference explicitly sais "If an inline function or variable (since C++17) with external linkage is defined differently in different translation units, the behavior is undefined.". So the stuff you wrote is GCC specific as it is a side effect of orchestration of the compilation and linkage processes. Also, notice that this might vary between versions.

Comment: I get that `inline` tells the linker to allow symbol collisions (sticking to the symbol from the first translation unit), but why on earth is it not required to test the symbols for equivalence? The standard should require compilers to provide LTO-information for all inline functions and make such checks mandatory!

Answer (score 30):

You still need to explicitly inline your function when doing template specialization (if specialization is in .h file)

Answer (score 24):

1) Nowadays, pretty much never.  If it's a good idea to inline a function, the compiler will do it without your help.

2) Always.  See #1.

(Edited to reflect that you broke your question into two questions...)

Comment: Yes. The inline is only a hint to the compiler, and it is free to ignore you. These days the compiler probably knows better than the programmer which functions are best to inline.

Comment: Yes, but it's less relevant - for a function to be inlined, it's body must be in the same compilation unit (for instance, in a header). That's less common in C programs.

Comment: While the compiler can do a good job today, do you know of any cases when you should write it?

Comment: defining a non-member function template (aka non-static function template) does not require inline.  See one definition rule(3.2/5).

Comment: -1: `inline` is still needed, for example to _define_ a function in a header file (and that is required for inlining such a function in several compilation units).

Comment: @Melebius : A function can be inlined in several compilation units without defining a function in a header file, and without using inline, the compiler has to be configured for that (In GCC this is called link time optimization, in visual studio whole program optimization).

Comment: @Étienne that's implementation-specific. Per standard, there's One Definition Rule, which means here that if you naively include the function definition in multiple translation units, you'll get an error. But if that function has `inline` specifier, its instances are automagically collapsed into one by the linker, and ODR isn't used.

Answer (score 16):

> When should I not write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method in C++?

If the function is declared in the header and defined in the `.cpp` file, you should *not* write the keyword.

> When will the the compiler not know when to make a function/method 'inline'?

There is no such situation. The compiler cannot make a function inline. All it can do is to inline some or all calls to the function. It can't do so if it hasn't got the code of the function (in that case the linker needs to do it if it is able to do so).

> Does it matter if an application is multithreaded when one writes 'inline' for a function/method?

No, that does not matter at all.

Comment: There are cases where it is appropriate to use inline in a .cpp file. E.g. applying optimizations to code that is entirely implementation specific.

Comment: @RobinDavies updated answer. It seems you misunderstood what I wanted to write.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb  __If the function is declared in the header and defined in the .cpp file, then you should not use the `inline` keyword.__ but `deft_code` (967 upvotes and Accepted answer) mention opposite to that  __you should only use `inline` keyword when the function's definition can show up in multiple translation units__  so  I checked it by declaring function in header file with keyword `inline` and defining it in .cpp file, it gives an error `undefined reference`. so you are right. Now also you mentioned,..........continue in next comment

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb ........ __code of function in multiple translation unit is not available to compiler so it can't make them inline so it's linkers job__ . in this sense, `deft_code` says that  __so you should use `inline` keyword so it gives compiler more info. to work with an optimizing code__   so his wording also makes sense here but when I try to use in code as mentioned early it gives error . so I feel both of your statements are opposite to each other but both of them makes sense but when I check practically  your statements is true , so can you please put some light on this.

Answer (score 7):

- When will the the compiler not know when to make a function/method 'inline'?

This depends on the compiler used. Do not blindly trust that nowadays compilers know better then humans how to inline and you should never use it for performance reasons, because it's linkage directive rather than optimization hint. While I agree that ideologically are these arguments correct encountering reality might be a different thing.

After reading multiple threads around I tried out of curiosity the effects of inline on the code I'm just working and the results were that I got measurable speedup for GCC and no speed up for Intel compiler.

(More detail: math simulations with few critical functions defined outside class, GCC 4.6.3 (g++ -O3), ICC 13.1.0 (icpc -O3); adding inline to critical points caused +6% speedup with GCC code).

So if you qualify GCC 4.6 as a modern compiler the result is that inline directive still matters if you write CPU intensive tasks and know where exactly is the bottleneck.

Comment: I'd like to see more evidence to back up your claims. Please provide code you are testing with as well as assembler output with and without inline keyword. Any number of things could have given you performance benefits.

Comment: Finally someone who doesn't only repeat what others say, but does actually verify those statements. Gcc does indeed still consider the inline keyword as a hint (I think clang ignores it completely).

Comment: @void.pointer: Why is this so hard to believe? If optimizers were perfect already, then new versions couldn't improve the program performance. But they regularly do.

Answer (score 3):

> gcc by default does not inline any functions when compiling without
>   optimization enabled. I don't know about visual studio – deft_code

I checked this for Visual Studio 9 (15.00.30729.01) by compiling with /FAcs and looking at the assembly code:
The compiler produced calls to member functions without optimization enabled in **debug** mode. Even if the function is marked with **__forceinline**, no inline runtime code is produced.

Comment: Enable /Wall to be told about which functions where marked inline but didn't actually get inlined

Answer (score 2):

In reality, pretty much never.  All you're doing is suggesting that the compiler make a given function inline (e.g., replace all calls to this function /w its body).  There are no guarantees, of course: the compiler may ignore the directive.

The compiler will generally do a good job of detecting + optimizing things like this.

Comment: The problem is that `inline` has a _semantic_ difference in C++ (e.g. in the way multiple definitions are treated), which is important in some cases (e.g. templates).

Comment: inline is used to resolve cases where a symbol has multiple definitions.  Templates however are already handled by the language.  One exception is a specialized template function that doesn't have any template paramters anymore (template<>).  These are treated more like functions than templates and so need the inline keyword in order to link.

Answer (score 1):

F.5: If a function is very small and time-critical, declare it inline

*Reason*: Some optimizers are good at inlining without hints from the programmer, but don’t rely on it. Measure! Over the last 40 years or so, we have been promised compilers that can inline better than humans without hints from humans. We are still waiting. Specifying inline (explicitly, or implicitly when writing member functions inside a class definition) encourages the compiler to do a better job.

Source: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#Rf-inline

For examples and exceptions, go to the Source (see above).

Answer (score 1):

One use case might occur on inheritance. For example, if all below cases are true:

- you have a base class of some class
- the base class needs to be abstract
- the base class has no pure virtual method other than destructor
- you don't want to create cpp file for the base class because in vain

then you have to define the destructor; otherwise, you will have some `undefined referance` linker errors. Moreover, you have to do not only define but also to define the destructor with inline keyword; otherwise, you will have `multiple definition` linker errors.

This may happen for some helper classes that contains only static methods or writing base exception classes etc.

Let's give an example:

Base.h:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base(SomeElementType someElement) noexcept : _someElement(std::move(someElement)) {}

    virtual ~Base() = 0;

protected:
    SomeElementType _someElement;
}

inline Base::~Base() = default;
```

Derived1.h:

```
#include "Base.h"

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
    Derived1(SomeElementType someElement) noexcept : Base(std::move(someElement)) {}

    void DoSomething1() const;
}
```

Derived1.cpp:

```
#include "Derived1.h"

void Derived1::DoSomething1() const {
    // use _someElement 
}
```

Derived2.h:

```
#include "Base.h"

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
    Derived2(SomeElementType someElement) noexcept : Base(std::move(someElement)) {}

    void DoSomething2() const;
}
```

Derived2.cpp:

```
#include "Derived2.h"

void Derived2::DoSomething2() const {
    // use _someElement 
}
```

Generally, abstract classes have some pure virtual methods other than constructor or destructor. So, you didn't have to seperate decleration and definition of virtual destructor of the base class, you could just write `virtual ~Base() = default;` on class decleration. However, in our case it's not like that.

As far as I know, MSVC allow you to write something like that on class decleration: `virtual ~Base() = 0 {}`. So you don't need to seperate decleration and definition with inline keyword. But it will only work with MSVC compiler.

Real world example:

BaseException.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class BaseException : public std::exception {
public:
    BaseException(std::string message) noexcept : message(std::move(message)) {}
    virtual char const* what() const noexcept { return message.c_str(); }

    virtual ~BaseException() = 0;

private:
    std::string message;
};

inline BaseException::~BaseException() = default;
```

SomeException.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "BaseException.h"

class SomeException : public BaseException {
public:
    SomeException(std::string message) noexcept : BaseException(std::move(message)) {}
};
```

SomeOtherException.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "BaseException.h"

class SomeOtherException : public BaseException {
public:
    SomeOtherException(std::string message) noexcept : BaseException(std::move(message)) {}
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <SomeException.h>
#include <SomeOtherException.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static int DoSomething(int argc) {
    try {
        switch (argc) {
        case 0:
            throw SomeException("some");
        case 1:
            throw SomeOtherException("some other");
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (const exception& ex) {
        cout << ex.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**) {
    return DoSomething(argc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ inline is totally different to [C inline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207045/7194773).

```
#include <iostream>
extern inline int i[];
int i [5];
struct c {
  int function (){return 1;} // implicitly inline
  static inline int j = 3; // explicitly inline
  static int k; // without inline, a static member has to be defined out of line
  static int f (){return 1;} // but a static method does not // implicitly inline
};

extern inline int b;
int b=3;
int c::k = 3; // when a static member is defined out of line it cannot have a static
              // specifier and if it doesn't have an `inline` specifier in the
              // declaration or on the definition then it is not inline and always
              // emits a strong global symbol in the translation unit

int main() {
  c j;
  std::cout << i;
}
```

`inline` on its own affects the compiler, assembler and the linker. It is a directive to the compiler saying only emit a symbol for this function/data if it's used in the translation unit, and if it is, then like class methods, tell the assembler to store them in the section `.section .text.c::function(),"axG",@progbits,c::function(),comdat` or `.section .bss.i,"awG",@nobits,i,comdat` for unitialised data or `.section .data.b,"awG",@progbits,b,comdat` for initialised data. Template instantiations also go in their own comdat groups.

This follows `.section name, "flags"MG, @type, entsize, GroupName[, linkage]`. For instance, the section name is `.text.c::function()`. `axG` means the section is allocatable, executable and in a group i.e. a group name will be specified (and there is no M flag so no entsize will be specified); `@progbits` means the section contains data and isn't blank; `c::function()` is the group name and the group has `comdat` linkage meaning that in all object files, all sections encountered with this group name tagged with comdat will be removed from the final executable except for 1 i.e. the compiler makes sure that there is only one definition in the translation unit and then tells the assembler to put it in its own group in the object file (1 section in 1 group) and then the linker will make sure that if any object files have a group with the same name, then only include one in the final .exe. The difference between `inline` and not using `inline` is now visible to the assembler and as a result the linker, because it's not stored in the regular `.data` or `.text` etc by the assembler due to their directives. Only inline symbols with external linkage are given external comdat linkage like this -- static linkage (local) symbols do not need to go in comdat groups.

`inline` on a non-static method declaration in a class makes the method inline if it is defined out-of-line, this will prevent the method being emitted in the translation unit if it is not referenced in the translation unit. The same effect is achieved by putting `inline` on the out-of-line definition. When a method is defined out-of-line without an `inline` specifier and the declaration in the class is not `inline` then it will emit a symbol for the method in the translation unit at all times because it will have external linkage rather than external comdat linkage. If the method is *defined* in the class then it is implicitly `inline`, which gives it external comdat linkage rather than external linkage.

`static inline` on a member in a class (as opposed to method) makes it a `static` member (which does not refer to its linkage -- it has the linkage of its class which may be extern). `static inline` also allows `static` members of the class to be defined inside the class instead of needing to be declared in the class and then defined out-of-line (without `static` in the definition, which wasn't allowed without `-fpermissive`). `*static inline*` also makes the members `inline` and not *`static inline`* -- `inline` means that the definition is only emitted if it is referenced in the translation unit. Previously you had to specify `inline` on the out-of-line definition to make the member `inline`.

Seeing as `static` methods can be defined in the class, `static inline` has no effect on the `static` method defined in the class, which always has external linkage, is a static method and is `inline`. If it is defined out of line then `inline` must be used to make it `inline` (i.e. to give to external comdat linkage rather than just external linkage), and `static` still can't be used.

`static inline` at file scope only affects the compiler. It means to the compiler: only emit a symbol for this function/data if it's used in the translation unit and do so as a regular static symbol (store in.text /.data without .globl directive). To the assembler there is now no difference between `static` and `static inline`. Like the other forms of `inline`, it cannot be used on a `class`, which is a type, but can be used on an object of the type of that class. This form of `static inline` also cannot be used on members or methods of a function, where it will always be treated `inline` as the `static` means something else in a class (it means that the class is acting as a scope rather than it being a member of or method to be used on an object).

`extern inline` is a declaration that means you must define this symbol in the translation unit if it is referenced or throw compiler error; if it's defined then treat it as a regular `inline` and to the assembler and linker there will be no difference between `extern inline` and `inline`, so this is a compiler guard only.

```
extern inline int i[];
extern int i[]; //allowed repetition of declaration with incomplete type, inherits inline property
extern int i[5]; //declaration now has complete type
extern int i[5]; //allowed redeclaration if it is the same complete type or has not yet been completed
extern int i[6]; //error, redeclaration with different complete type
int i[5]; //definition, must have complete type and same complete type as the declaration if there is a declaration with a complete type
```

The whole of the above without the error line collapses to `inline int i[5]`. Obviously if you did `extern inline int i[] = {5};` then `extern` would be ignored due to the explicit definition through assignment.

I think the reason that `static` is not allowed on a `static` out-of-line definition without `-fpermissive` is because it implies that the static refers to `static` linkage, because it's not immediately obvious to the programmer that it is a member of a class or whether that class has , where the `static` means something different. `-fpermissive` ignores the `static` specifier on the out-of-line definition and it means nothing. In the case of a simple integer, `k` can't be defined out of a namespace, if `c` were a namespace, but if `k` were a function, then there would be no way of visibly telling from the line of code whether it is an out of line definition of a function in a namespace with `static` linkage, or an out-of-line definition of a static member with external linkage, and may give the wrong impression to the programmer / reader of the code.

For local classes, `inline` on a member / method will result in a compiler error and members and methods have no linkage.

For `inline` on a namespace, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60901989/7194773) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176886/7194773)

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are writing a library or have special reasons, you can forget about `inline` and use *link-time optimization* instead. It removes the requirement that a function definition must be in a header for it to be considered for inlining across compilation units, which is precisely what `inline` allows.

(But see [Is there any reason why not to use link time optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23736507/is-there-any-reason-why-not-to-use-link-time-optimization))

Answer (score -1):

***Inline*** keyword requests the compiler to replace the function call with the body of the function ,it first evaluates the expression and then passed.It reduces the function call overhead as there is no need to store the return address and stack memory is not required for function arguments.

When to use:

> - To Improve performance
> - To reduce call overhead .
> - As it's just a request to the compiler, certain functions won't be inlined 
>      *large functions
>
>   - functions having too many conditional arguments
>   - recursive code and code with loops etc.

Comment: It may benefit you to know that this isn't actually the case. The optimisation level -O0 through - Ofast is what determines whether a function is inlined or not. Inline on regular compilation (-O0) will not inline a function regardless of whether you use `inline` or not in C and C++.  C Inline: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287072/7194773 C++ inline:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62230963/7194773

Comment: @LewisKelsey: Commercial compilers often interpret such things usefully even if free compilers don't.  Even if a compiler was able to determine with absolute certainty that in-line expanding a particular call site would cause a 10% increase in a program's overall code size while reducing the execution time of a loop by 5%, it would have no way of knowing whether or not that would represent a good tradeoff.  If the loop in question needed to process data that arrived at a certain rate and would take 95% of CPU time without such optimization, reducing the execution time of the loop by 5%...

Comment: ...could double the performance of everything outside the loop.  MAJOR win.

Answer (score -2):

You want to put it in the very beginning, before return type. But most Compilers ignore it. If it's defined, and it has a smaller block of code, most compilers consider it inline anyway.

Answer (score -2):

When developing and debugging code, leave `inline` out.  It complicates debugging.

The major reason for adding them is to help optimize the generated code.  Typically this trades increased code space for speed, but sometimes `inline` saves both code space and execution time.

Expending this kind of thought about performance optimization before algorithm completion is [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimization#When_to_optimize).

Comment: `inline` functions are typically not inlined unless compiling with optimizations, so they do not affect debugging in any way. Remember that it's a hint, not a demand.

Comment: gcc by default does not inline any functions when compiling without optimization enabled.  I don't know about visual studio

Comment: I worked on an enormous g++ project which had debugging enabled.  Maybe other options prevented it, but the `inline` functions were inlined.  It was impossible to set a meaningful breakpoint in them.

Comment: enabling debugging doesn't stop inlining in gcc.  If any optimization where enabled (-O1 or greater), then gcc will try to inline the most obvious cases.  Traditionally GDB has had a hard time with breakpoints and constructors especially inline constructors.  But, that has been fixed in recent versions (at least 6.7, maybe sooner).

Comment: Adding `inline` will do nothing to improve the code on a modern compiler, which can figure out whether to inline or not on its own.

Answer (score -3):

When one should inline :

1.When one want to avoid overhead of things happening when function is called like parameter passing , control transfer, control return etc.

2.The function should be small,frequently called and making inline is really advantageous since as per 80-20 rule,try to make those function inline which has major impact on program performance.

As we know that inline is just a request to compiler similar to register and it will cost you at Object code size.

Comment: "inline is just a request to compiler similar to register" They're similar because neither are requests or have anything to do with optimisation. `inline` has lost its status as an optimisation hint, and most compilers  only use it to make allowances for multiple definitions - as IMO they should. More so, since C++11, `register` has fully been deprecated for its prior meaning of 'I know better than the compiler how to optimise': it's now just a reserved word with no current meaning.

Comment: @underscore_d: Gcc still listens to `inline` to some degree.