# Are private variable visible outside of the class if they are static?

Tags: c++, static, visibility, private

In the following example (taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyh8hetw.aspx)) we have a private static variable x and then we change its name outside of the class. What confuses me is why is it allowed to change a private variable outside of the class? What is then the reason to declare it a `private`.

```
// static_member_functions.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

class StaticTest
{
private:
    static int x;
public:
    static int count()
    {
        return x;
    }
};

int StaticTest::x = 9;

int main()
{
    printf_s("%d\n", StaticTest::count());
}
```

Comment: I answered myself  exactly the same question in this post. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not "changing the variable", it's *defining* it.

Every `static` member must be *defined* outside the class (`static int x;` is just a declaration; if you remove `int StaticTest::x = 9;` there will be a linker error saying something like "undefined reference to `StaticTest::x`").

---

Try changing it in the `main`, for example:

```
StaticTest::x = 13;
```

and you'll get the error, you expected (`error: ‘int StaticTest::x’ is private`).

Comment: by defining do you mean initializing it? its definition is in the class

Comment: @QuantumKarl - no, by "defining" I mean "defining", not "initializing". This is an "exception" for the `static` members. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c (the second answer) for more detailed information.

Comment: @QuantumKarl - the class **definition** contains a **declaration** of the static data member. You also have to **define** the static data member, and that has to be done outside the class definition.

Comment: @Pete Becker + Kiril kirov thanks for clarifying the difference. I don't use static variables much. at uni I was taught to try avoid them. Any idea why?

Comment: @QuantumKarl - depends on the needs. Sometimes `static` is your only (or the best) option. The most significant difference is, that a `static` member is shared between _all_ instances of the class. In this case, if you have 10 objects `StaticTest`, all of them will share the same `x`.

Comment: I answered myself  exactly the same question in this post. Thank sfor the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not changed outside the class.

Consider this slightly modified example:

```
class StaticTest
{
    private:
        static int x;

    public:
        static int count();
};

int StaticTest::x = 9;

int StaticTest::count()
{
    return x;
}
```

Neither is `x` *initialized* "outside the class*, nor is it *accessed* outside of it. The `class { }` block merely *declares* the class members. The `StaticTest::` scope qualifier tells the compiler that the subsequent *definitions* of `x` and `count()` are part of the `StaticTest` class.

Try accessing `x` from your `main()`:

```
int main()
{
    printf_s("%d\n", StaticTest::x);
}
```

You will see that it is not possible, since `x` is private.

This is done so that you can seperate the declaration (in the .hpp header file) from the implementation (in the .cpp implementation file). (This breaks once you start using templates, but nothing is perfect.)

Comment: I cannot compile your first example. `static int StaticTest::count()` cannot be declared.

Comment: @Roman: Sorry. No `static` at point of definition. (The same as for `x`, by the way.) This is not related to the point of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Access control doesn't affect visibility: private members of
a class are visible everywhere, regardless of whether they are
static or not.

Access control affects "access" (not visibility) to names or
symbols, not to the entities they manage, and it affects access
to all names, regardless of what they name.  Because access
control doesn't affect visibility, name lookup will find the
names, but if you don't have access, it will be an error (even
if there is an entity with the same name to which you do have
access).

With regards to your example, I don't understand the problem.
The only access to `StaticTest::x` is in the member function
`StaticTest::count()`.  Why should this be a problem?