# Proper way to create static instance of a class inside of itself

Tags: c++

I have a pixel struct.  I want to decalre static constants inside of it for colors like BLACK and WHITE.  I am writing all of the in a header file which will be included in multiple cpp files.

```
struct Pixel
{
    typedef uint16_t quantum_t; 
    static const quantum_t MAX_QUANTUM = 0xffffL;
    static const quantum_t MIN_QUANTUM = 0;
    static const int QUANTUM_BITS = 16;

    quantum_t r, g, b;

    Pixel(quantum_t r_ = 0, quantum_t g_ = 0, quantum_t b_ = 0) :
        r(r_), g(g_), b(b_) { }

    template<typename T>
    static T clamp(T x)
    {
        return x > MAX_QUANTUM ? MAX_QUANTUM : (x < MIN_QUANTUM ? MIN_QUANTUM : x);
    }

    template<typename T>
    static Pixel clamp(T r, T g, T b)
    {
        return Pixel(clamp(r), clamp(g), clamp(b));
    }

    static const Pixel BLACK;
    static const Pixel WHITE;
};

const Pixel Pixel::BLACK(0, 0, 0);
const Pixel Pixel::WHITE(Pixel::MAX_QUANTUM, Pixel::MAX_QUANTUM, Pixel::MAX_QUANTUM);
```

Initially I tried to initialize the static BLACK and WHITE inside ofthe struct however I got an error from g++ about having an incomplete type.  Once I declared the static variables outside of the struct the error went away and the code now compiles.  This is a header only library and what I am wondering is will declaring the static variables like this cause compilation issues if it is included in multiple cpp files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Defining static members in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will declaring the static variables like this cause compilation issues
>   if it is included in multiple cpp files?

No, because the C++ standard allows this particular usage and unless they are declared `extern` they will not be seen or collide with other instances of the same named variable in other translation units (i.e. cpp files).