# static library offers static integration through interface

Tags: c++

I am actually creating a static library (.lib) which will use a logger. I would like to offer the integrator the possibility of use his own logger.

To do that I tried to used static virtual pure function but I saw that this is impossible (there is a lot of topic about it)

Here is what I would like,

From static lib

```
enum class LogLevel final
{
  kLogLevelTrace,
  kLogLevelDebug,
  kLogLevelInfo,
  kLogLevelWarn,
  kLogLevelError,
  kLogLevelCritical,
  kLogLevelOff,
};    

class ILogger
{
public:
  virtual ~ILogger() = default;
  virtual void TestLogMessage(const LogLevel& log_level, const std::string& log_message) = 0;
};

class Logger final
{
public:
  static Logger& GetLogger()
  {
    static Logger logger;
    return logger;
  }

  static void LogMessage(const AltLogLevel& log_level, const std::string& log_message)
  {
      ILogger::TestLogMessage(log_level, log_message);
  }
};
```

From integration:

```
class CustomLogger final : public ILogger
{
public:
  void TestLogMessage(const LogLevel& log_level, const std::string& log_message) override
  {
    std::cout << log_message << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Without success. So I tried something like:

```
class Logger final
{
public:
  static Logger& GetLogger()
  {
    static Logger logger;
    return logger;
  }

  static void SetLogger(const std::shared_ptr<ILogger>& logger)
  {
      custom_logger_ = std::move(logger);
  }

  static void LogMessage(const LogLevel& log_level, const std::string& log_message)
  {
    if (custom_logger_ )
    {
      custom_logger_->TestLogMessage(log_level, log_message);
    }
  }
private:
    static std::shared_ptr<ILogger> custom_logger_ ;
};
```

and integration side:

```
class CustomLogger final : public ILogger
{
public:
  void TestLogMessage(const LogLevel& log_level, const std::string& log_message) override
  {
    std::cout << log_message << std::endl;
  }
};


static const std::shared_ptr<ILogger> custom_logger = std::make_shared<CustomLogger>();

Logger::SetLogger (custom_logger);
```

But I got link issue.

What is my best solution here?
May I just have to use lambda configuration?

Comment: `static` means the method does not depend on an instance. `virtual` means what method is called depends on the instance. "static virtual" is an oxymoron. You need to describe what you think this would be good for.

Comment: For your first approach, think about what would happen if the integration side also defined `class OverrideLogger final : public ILogger { /*...*/ };`. What would it mean to have two classes derived from `ILogger`?

Comment: *"But I got link issue."* -- What's the link issue? Is it because nowhere in your code do you define `custom_logger_` (with an underscore at the end), much less as a member of `Logger`? This looks suspiciously like a typo...

Comment: I have updated, I create custom_logger_ with the make_shared line.
about having "two classes derived from `ILogger`" This is not the idea, I would like to use internal class which call the derived implemented class.

Comment: @LoganGallois *"This is not the idea,"* -- You mean that this is not **your** idea. When you design a library, never assume that the consumer will follow your ideas. They will mess up. They will try things that "seem to work". They will blame you when "seems to work" suddenly breaks. So keep in mind what *could* be done, even when it's not what *should* be done, and make it easy for the consumer to do the right thing, hard to do the wrong. *If it's easy to do the wrong thing, revisit your design. It could be a sign that there's a better approach.*

Comment: @LoganGallois *"I create custom_logger_ with the make_shared line."* -- No you do not. You create `custom_logger`, not `custom_logger_` (and it's not a member of `Logger`). Hmm... that's on the integration side, so maybe the question is [Defining static members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3536372). Still, without the exact error message, this is just guesswork and mindreading.

Comment: A stream buffer could be a solution for logging, integration side can redirect it to a file or  to there output stream or just let it go when it is not important for them.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put : do NOT integrate a logging mechanism into your library.
It might not be the logging system the client of your library wants to use.

When your code needs to log something that something happened create an abstract baseclass, lets call it `MyLibraryReportingItf` and for each thing your library can log (report) add one virtual method. e.g. `void report_file_not_found(const std::string&filename) const noexcept = 0`. And call this method on the line you had your log statement. Start up with an empty/null implementation of this interface. And now let the client inject an implementation of this interface into your library. Now a user of your library can create and adapter to the logging infrastructure the client needs

So something like this :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyLibraryReportingItf
{
public:
    virtual ~MyLibraryReportingItf() = default;

    virtual void report_file_not_found(const std::string& file_name) const noexcept = 0; // reporting should not change state and not throw any errors!
};

class MyLibraryNullReporting : public MyLibraryReportingItf
{
    void report_file_not_found(const std::string& file_name) const noexcept override
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
};

class MyLibraryStdIOReporting : public MyLibraryReportingItf
{
    void report_file_not_found(const std::string& file_name) const noexcept override
    {
        std::cout << "File not found: " << file_name << "\n";
    }
};

// You can even hook up to your logger infrastructure

struct ILogger
{
    virtual ~ILogger() = default;
    virtual void TestLogMessage(const int log_level, const std::string& log_message) = 0;
};

class YourLoggerReporting : public MyLibraryReportingItf
{
public:
    YourLoggerReporting(ILogger& yourLogger) :
        m_yourLogger(yourLogger)
    {
    }

    void report_file_not_found(const std::string& file_name) const noexcept override
    {
        try
        {
            m_yourLogger.TestLogMessage(1, "File not found: " + file_name);
        }
        catch(...)
        {
        }
    }

private:
    ILogger& m_yourLogger;
};

struct my_library
{
    my_library(MyLibraryReportingItf& reporting) :
        reporting(reporting)
    {
    }

    void open_file(const std::string& file_name)
    {
        // Open file
        // If file not found
        reporting.report_file_not_found(file_name);
    }

    MyLibraryReportingItf& reporting;
};

int main()
{
    // Now the client of your lib can make an instance of
    // the log adapter they need.
    MyLibraryStdIOReporting reporting;

    // and inject it into the library
    my_library lib(reporting);
    lib.open_file("file.txt");
}
```

This is a kind of double dependency injection that really decouples your library code from any kind of assumptions on how logging is implemented. It also allows you to write unit tests without any dependency on a file system. You can even create a google mock for your reporting interface to check calls to reporting are made in the situations where something should be reported (logged).

Comment: Yeah that was my first use ! But this is boring to add the ILogger to each class which need to log something. This is why I would like to use static method.

Comment: The level of boringness is a bad indicator of good design... other engineering disciplines already now discipline is needed to make quality products (and discipline can be boring/repetitive) ;)
You can still have the reporting interface as of a global state in your library.
Startup with the null logger, and then allow clients to replace that null instance with their report class.  E.g. by making an InitiLibrary(theirReportingImplementation) call.

Comment: And NOTE I am NOT injecting an ILogger, I am injecting a report interface defined by the library itself. All knowledge about how to convert these reports to the actual logging should outside your code. Your code should know nothing about levels, since maybe the actual logging system of your client doesn't have them at all. Keep  the interaction lean, simple and clean.. just report methods one for each situation.

Comment: Ok but what if I want to use MyLibraryReportingItf in other classes, I have to inject it for each classes which want to report, isn't it?

Comment: The pragmatic middleground : Within your library you could let classes lookup the global reportingItf you set with the InitLibrary call.  So you inject it in the library and let internal classes pick it up from some known location. E.g. through a getter function or a global variable (pointer to the MyLibraryReportingItf which is initialized at startup to the null strategy) and which you will modify with the InitLibraryCall

Comment: "The level of boringness is a bad indicator of good design" I tend to disagree. The more boring the better, so we can spend our time with the interesting stuff ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That is what I meant.. but thanks for clarifying :) I like my designs boring, build small "lego" blocks which by themselves maybe boring... but O the things you can build from them :)