# Why do C++ template definitions need to be in the header?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the implementation and the declaration of a template class be in the same header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749099/why-should-the-implementation-and-the-declaration-of-a-template-class-be-in-the-s)

e.g when defining a template class why do the implementations of the class methods need to be in the header? Why can't they be in a implementation file (cpp/cxx)?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of I don't know which question :)

Comment: I could not find a question like that either...

Comment: They can, you just usually don't want them to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A template class is not a class, it's a *template* that can be used to create a class. When you instantiate such a class, e.g. `MyTemplate<int>`, the compiler creates the class on the spot. In order to create it, it has to see all the templated member functions (so that it can use the templates to create actual member functions such as `MyTemplate<int>::foo()` ), and therefore these templated member functions must be in the header.

If the members are not in the header, the compiler will simply assume that they exist somewhere else and just create actual function declarations from the templated function declarations, and this gives you linker errors.

The "export" keyword is supposed to fix this, but few compilers support it (I only know of Comeau).

You can also explicitly instantiate `MyTemplate<int>` - then the compiler will create actual member functions for `MyTemplate<int>` when it compiles the cpp files containing the `MyTemplate` member function definition templates.

Comment: "A template class is not a class" - which is why we should call it a "class template", not a "template class" as in the question.

Comment: The `export` keyword is supported by only a vendor (and I think that it had some quirks). That same vendor pushed to remove it from the upcoming standard, which is as much as saying that it is non-existent in the language.

Comment: So you can have them in the cpp file if you explicitly declare the types?

Answer (score 4):

They need to be visible for the compiler when they are instantiated. That basically means that if you are publishing the template in a header, the definitions have to be visible by all translation units that include that header if you depend on implicit instantiation.

They need not be defined in the header if you are going to explicitly instantiate the templates, but this is in most cases not a good idea.

As to the reason, it basically boils down to the fact that templates are not compiled when the compiler parses the definition, but rather when they are instantiated, and then they are compiled for the particular instantiation type.

Comment: @EricSchaefer: I have edited the answer: the reason is that templates are not compiled when they are parsed, but rather when they are instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports `export`, then it doesn't. Only EDG-based compilers support `export`, and it's going to be removed from C++0x because of that.

Non-exported templates require that the compiler can see the full template definition, in order to instantiate it for the particular types you supply as arguments. For example:

```
template<typename T> 
struct X {
    T t;
    X(int i): t(i) {}
};
```

Now, when you write `X<float>(5)` in some translation unit, the compiler *as part of compiling that translation unit* must check that the constructor of X is type-correct, generate the code for it, and so on. Hence it must see the definition of X, so that it can permit `X<float>(5)` but forbid `X<char*>(5)`.

The only sensible way to ensure that the compiler sees the same template definition in all translation units that use it, is to put the definition in a header file. As far as the standard is concerned, though, you're welcome to copy-and-paste it manually, or to define a template in a cpp file that is used only in that one translation unit.

`export` in effect tells the compiler that it must output a parsed form of the template definition into a special kind of object file. Then the linker performs template instantiation. With normal toolchains, the compiler is smart enough to perform template instantiation and the linker isn't. Bear in mind that template instantiation has to do pretty much *everything* that the compiler does beyond basic parsing.

Answer (score 1):

They can be in a CPP file.

The problem arises from the fact that the compiler builds the code for a specific instantiation of a template class (eg std::vector< int >) on a per translation unit basis.  The problem with defining the functions in a CPP file is that you will need to define every possible form in that CPP file (this is called template specialization).

So for that int vector exampled above you could define a function in a CPP file for the int case using specialization.

e.g

```
template<> void std::vector< int >::push_back( int& intVal )
```

Of course doing this can produce the advantage of optimisation for specific cases but it does give you an idea of just how much code bloat can be introduced by STL!  At least all the functions aren't defined as inline as a certain compiler used to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

That aspect of template is called the compilation model, not to be confused with the instantiation mechanism which was the subject of [How does C++ link template instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094908/how-does-c-link-template-instances).

The instantiation mechanism is the answer to the question "When is the instantiation generated?", the instantiation model is the answer to "Where the source are found?"

There are two standards compilation model:

- inclusion, the one that you know, where the definition must be available,
- separated, which allows to put the definition somewhere else with the help of the keyword `export`.  That one has been removed from the standard and won't be available in C++0X.  One of the raison for removal was that it wasn't widely implemented (only one implementation).

See C++ Templates, The Complete Guide by David Vandevoorde and Nicolai Josuttis or http://www.bourguet.org/v2/cpplang/export.pdf for more information, the separated compilation model being the subject of that later paper.