# Error with using defaults in copy constructor of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, linker, defaults

I have the following templated classes,

```
template <typename Real>
class Marker {

 typedef Wm5::Vector3<Real> Position ;
 typedef Wm5::Vector3<Real> Normal ;
 typedef Wm5::Vector3<Real> Color ;

 public:

  Marker(int id = -1, Position position = Wm5::Vector3<Real>::ZERO, Normal normal = Wm5::Vector3<Real>::ZERO, Color color = Wm5::Vector3<Real>::ZERO)
: id_(id), position_(position), normal_(normal), color_(color), cluster_(-1) {}

  ~Marker() {}

 private:

  int id_ ;
  Position position_ ;
  Normal normal_ ; 
  Color color_ ;
  int cluster_ ;

};


template <typename T> 
class MarkerSet {

    typedef Marker<T> MarkerT ;      
    typedef std::vector<MarkerT> MarkerVector ;

public:

    MarkerSet::MarkerSet(int id = -1, MarkerVector markers = MarkerVector()) 
   {id_ = id; markers_ = markers;}      

   MarkerSet::~MarkerSet() {}

private:

    int id_ ;   
    MarkerVector markers_ ;

} ;
```

When I try to create a MarkerSet object by

```
MarkerSet<double> markerSet ;
```

Getting this linker error,

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall     MarkerSet<double>::MarkerSet<double>(int,class std::vector<class Marker<double>,class std::allocator<class Marker<double> > >)" (??0?$MarkerSet@N@@QAE@HV?$vector@V?$Marker@N@@V?$allocator@V?$Marker@N@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
```

I would be extremely grateful if somebody could give me a pointer in the right direction with regards to what I have done wrong.

Edit:

Ok I have narrowed it down to something rather odd.

in .h

```
  MarkerSet(int id = -1, MarkerVector markers = MarkerVector()) 
{id_ = id; markers_ = markers;}
```

builds fine

Rather than in .h

```
 MarkerSet(int id = -1, MarkerVector markers = MarkerVector()) ;
```

in .cpp

```
 template <typename T>
 MarkerSet<T>::MarkerSet(int id, MarkerVector markers) {

  id_ = id ;
  markers_ = markers ;

}
```

Errors out in the way described above.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it possible you have a stale object file around which used an older definition of `MarkerSet`?  Try your IDE's "clean" or "rebuild all" option?

Comment: Yes I have tried a clean and rebuild all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using a different compiler? I tried playing with it and the following works fine for me with gcc. I eliminated the Wm5 members as I don't have those. Pasting the header and cpp:

test.h

```
#include <vector>

template <typename Real>
class Marker {

 public:

  Marker(int id = -1,int _position=1)
    : id_(id), position(_position){}

  ~Marker() {}

 private:

  int id_ ;
  int position ;
  Real r;

};


template <typename T> 
class MarkerSet {

    typedef Marker<T> MarkerT ;      
    typedef std::vector<MarkerT> MarkerVector ;

public:

    MarkerSet(int id = -1, MarkerVector markers = MarkerVector()) 
      {id_ = id; markers_ = markers;std::cout<<"Called"<<std::endl;}      

   ~MarkerSet() {}

private:

    int id_ ;   
    MarkerVector markers_ ;

} ;
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  cout<<"Hello"<<endl;
  MarkerSet<double> ms;
  return -1;

}
```

cmd:

```
bash$ ./test
Hello
Called
bash$
```

Template class definition need to be in the header:

[Why do C++ template definitions need to be in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180357/why-do-c-template-definitions-need-to-be-in-the-header)

Comment: Ok I have got it to build now on my VS2010 machine....I have no idea what is different between this                           MarkerSet(int id = -1, MarkerVector markers = MarkerVector()) {id_ = id; markers_ = markers;std::cout<<"Called"<<std::endl;}                                             and                                                       MarkerSet(int id = -1, MarkerVector markers = MarkerVector()) ; in .h and template <typename T>
MarkerSet<T>::MarkerSet(int id, MarkerVector markers) {id_ = id ;
markers_ = markers ;} in the .cpp files

Comment: I am not including MarkerSet<T>:: before the function names. As definition is inside of the class you don't need to qualify by class name. gcc actually complained about it. Also all definitions are in the header as these are template classes.

Comment: I understand. See edit above as clearer explanation of problem still having.

Comment: You cannot put template class definitions in .cpp files. You need to put them in the headers for them to be available at compile time. This must be your issue. Here, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180357/why-do-c-template-definitions-need-to-be-in-the-header

Comment: Done...Still getting the hang of this stack overflow thing :-)

Answer (score 0):

May it be so that you do not `#include` actual contructor body so that the linker does not generate required code for `MarkerSet<double>::MarkerSet<double>(int,class std::vector<class Marker<double>,class std::allocator<class Marker<double> > >)"`?

Comment: Just tried changing the extra-qualified possibility and still getting the same error. Using VS2010 as compiler.

Comment: I am not sure quite what you mean by "do not #include actual constructor body".

Comment: SOrry, I meant exactly what Sid suggested, either moving constructor body to the header, or #include cpp-file with the body, not only include header with prototype. My bad, I should have clarified it.