# C++ template specialization for member function

Tags: c++, templates, member, specialization

I'm trying to implement a very basic `Vector3` (`Vec3`) class.
I'm struggling with a special case : `Vec3<size_t>` addition with `Vec3<int>`.

How can I make a template specialization for this case?

Any help would be appreciated.
Ben

```
#include <array>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

// #define Vec3f std::array<float, 3>
// #define Vec3u std::array<size_t, 3>

#define Vec3f Vec3<float>
#define Vec3u Vec3<size_t>
#define Vec3i Vec3<int>

template <typename T>
class Vec3
{
    public:
        Vec3(): _a() {}
        Vec3(T x, T y, T z): _a({x, y, z}) {}
        Vec3(const Vec3<T> & a): _a({a[0], a[1], a[2]}) {}

        ~Vec3() {}

        /// Print Vec3.
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Vec3<T> & v)
        {
            os << "(" << v[0] << ", " << v[1] << ", " << v[2] << ")";
            return os;
        }

        inline typename std::array<T, 3>::reference operator[](size_t i)
        {
            return _a[i];
        }

        inline typename std::array<T, 3>::const_reference operator[](size_t i) const
        {
            return _a[i];
        }


        /// Test equality.
        inline bool operator==(const Vec3<T> & other) const
        {
            bool a = abs(_a[0] - other._a[0]) < 1e-6;
            bool b = abs(_a[1] - other._a[1]) < 1e-6;
            bool c = abs(_a[2] - other._a[2]) < 1e-6;
            return (a and b and c);
        }

        /// Test non-equality.
        inline bool operator!=(const Vec3<T> & other) const
        {
            return not (*this == other);
        }


        /// Vec3 same type addition.
        inline Vec3<T> operator+(const Vec3<T> & other) const
        {
            return {_a[0] + other[0], _a[1] + other[1], _a[2] + other[2]};
        }


    protected:
        std::array<T, 3> _a;
};
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: As an FYI you don't need to use inline on all of your functions. see: [Is “inline” implicit in C++ member functions defined in class definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192077/is-inline-implicit-in-c-member-functions-defined-in-class-definition)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is to find the common type between `size_t` and `int` that is the template argument for the result.
This is a possible solution:

```
/// Vec3 addition between vectors of different base type.
template <class U>
Vec3<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type> operator+(const Vec3<U> & other) const
{
    return{ _a[0] + other[0], _a[1] + other[1], _a[2] + other[2] };
}
```

Comment: Depending of expected result `Vec3<decltype(declval<T>() + declval<U>())>` may be used instead of `common_type` (`char + char` is `int`, but its common type is `char`)

Comment: @Jarod42: thanks for the comment, it's a point of view I missed. But I have found some contexts in which the rule char+char->int was ok, since it prevented overflows (context was RGB pixels, the problem was that the int based pixel had,sooner or later, to be converted somehow back to char version)

Comment: Thank you both for your help. Unfortunately, this is not as restrictive as I would like. I'd like a function **specifically** to add `Vec3<size_t>` and `Vec3<int>`. Both your solutions are too permissive as they implement `Vec3<size_t>` and `Vec3<float>` addition too, for instance.