# Inline functions in a class

Tags: c++, class, inline

Is it true that if a function body is defined inside a class, the compiler will mark it inline? (even if not marked by the writer)

example:

```
class F {
public:
    void func() {
    std::cout << "is this inline?\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: @PaulR Here's a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9192077/3425536

Comment: @zenith: thanks, yes - that one is better (there were too many to choose from!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

> `[C++14: 9.3/2]:` **A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in which case it is an inline member function** (7.1.2), or it may be defined outside of its class definition if it has already been declared but not defined in its class definition. *[..]*

However, whether this has any observable effects beyond the associated linkage requirements is only as predictable as the `inline` keyword ever is.

The reason for this rule is so that it is legal to include the class definition — member functions and all — via a header into multiple translation units. You would have *multiple reference* linker errors otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you state the body of a function inside a class, it is equivalent to defining that function outside the class and prefixing it with the inline keyword, but whether or not it will be inlined is ultimately up to the compiler.