# Can I make a reference member no space taken?

Tags: c++

Is there any way I can make reference members take no space?
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

struct MyClass : public glm::vec3{
  float& rx = x;
  float& ry = y;
  float& rz = z;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << sizeof(glm::vec3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(MyClass) << std::endl;
}
```

the size of the class `glm::vec3` is 12 and the size of the class `MyClass` is 40.

Is there any way I can make the references in `MyClass` takes no space? Just act as if all codes where `ri` is used, it is replaced by `i`?

P.S. If you curious why I'm doing this, I'm adding custom attributes on class members for scanning, but I cannot change third-party codes like glm, that's why I need a wrapper, but if the wrapper is not the same size as the origin one, the space wasted is unacceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
struct MyClass : public glm::vec3{
  float& rx() { return x; }
  float& ry() { return y; }
  float& rz() { return z; }
};
```

Hard to say from your problem description if that is a possibility.

Comment: make it inline. than there will be no function at all too.

Comment: I think that's an option, but I need to change my scanning code to search methods as well, currently it just searching fields, I'll do this if I have no choice. Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: @IS, in modern C++ `inline` is not really used to inline anything. A compiler is already smart enough to inline what should be inlined. `inline` is for a linker, and `inline` is not needed here (these member functions are [implicitly inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192077/is-inline-implicit-in-c-member-functions-defined-in-class-definition)).

Answer (score 2):

Reference is an object, if you add it, you make your struct bigger.
You can add custom constexpr getters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

struct MyClass : public glm::vec3
{
  constexpr float& ref_x() { return x; }  
  constexpr float& ref_y() { return y; }  
  constexpr float& ref_z() { return z; }

  // you can also have a nice const overload
  constexpr const float& ref_x() const { return x; }  
  constexpr const float& ref_y() const { return y; }  
  constexpr const float& ref_z() const { return z; }
};

int main() 
{
  static_assert(sizeof(glm::vec3) == sizeof(MyClass));
  std::cout << sizeof(glm::vec3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << sizeof(MyClass) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cant. Every variable has an address on storage and comsume memeory. You can just search variable definition itself. This is from internet.

```
**A variable definition tells the compiler where and how much storage to create for the variable.**
```