# performance impact of "hot" and "inline" combination for a function definition

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-optimization

I have a function which does just few operations such as increments. I have declared that as `inline` and with the `__attribute__((hot))`.

[Gcc Doc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) suggests following for `hot` attribute:

> The hot attribute is used to inform the compiler that a function is a
>   hot spot of the compiled program. The function is optimized more
>   aggressively and on many target it is placed into special subsection
>   of the text section so all hot functions appears close together
>   improving locality.

which can be interpreted as for non `inline` hot functions they would be placed in lower address area of the process address map. But `inline` functions calls are supposed be literally replaced by their code. So question is how does combination of `inline` and `hot` really works ?

Answer (score 1):

See [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method) for a pretty good explanation of the `inline` keyword. It seems like a contradiction to declare a function as `hot` *and* `inline`; if the function is not defined in a header file, or is not defined in multiple compilation units then you should not declare it as `inline`.

Indeed, the decision to replace the function call with the function definition and place it "in-line" is up to the compiler. So the combination of `inline` and `hot` likely just ignores the `inline` part and places it in the `text.hot` section of the program. The linker is the only part of the process that really cares about the `inline` keyword, and then it doesn't necessarily do what you might think it does.