# Does it help marking methods as inline in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I think I know what the *inline* keyword does (it seems I don't), but with today's compilers (Visual Studio 2012's C++ compiler in my case), is it respected by the compiler or does the compiler ignore it and inlines the methods it deems good for it?

Comment: The latter. At least with optimizations turned on.

Comment: Remember that `inline` is just a _hint_, it doesn't mean the inlining is mandatory.

Comment: Yes, it helps **a lot** when you have a non-template function defined in a header.

Comment: And the absence of inline doesn't mean that inlining is prohibited.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato No, native C++

Comment: CPU with a poor branching gains with this?

Comment: "I know what the *inline* keyword does" -- no, you do not appear to.  Mind if I edit your question to say "I *think* I know"?  :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `inline` keyword is somehow unrelated to *inlining*. It actually means: multiple definitions of this function can appear in different translation units in the same program without it being a violation of the One Definition Rule.

Use it only for that, that is, if you define a function in a header, then mark it as `inline` (so that multiple translation units that include the header and thus generate the function can be linked together).

Comment: Yes, but only if the method is defined outside the class, in the header.

Comment: @ScottJones: Member functions defined inside the class are implicitly `inline`, as template functions (from the ODR point of view).

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you're using Visual Studio 2012, so there are some Microsoft-specific specifiers you can use to force the inlining behavior you want.

Normally, the compiler uses its own judgment to determine when functions should be inlined. However, if you know (because you have some context or knowledge of the application which the compiler cannot get by statically analyzing the source code) that something should be inlined for sure and want to override the compiler's judgment, you can use the `__forceinline` keyword.

It should be noted that there's no guarantee that a particular function will be inlined, even when using `__forceinline`, though, so it's not safe to think of it as anything other than a strong suggestion to the compiler.

In the majority of cases, it's best to leave the decision to the compiler, and if you want to further optimize based on runtime behavior, to use something like profile-guided optimization (PGO) which will choose how to optimize (including which functions to inline) based on what code paths are actually hit most frequently at runtime.