# Should i use inline function my program?

Tags: c++, c, inline

I have a **2500** line and **76.8** kb c++ console program. I learned **inline function** but heard about inline function makes a trouble in **huge programs**. Is it true? This program is huge or not. It can be a trouble in the future. What should i do or what is your suggestion for me.

Note:Program include lots of functions.
Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry about optimization until you run into issues; it's the root of all evil: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: A 2500 line program is not huge.  By some estimates, Microsoft Office is made of over 30 million lines of code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method)

Comment: @user814064: you should have posted this as answer

Comment: Don't trust any mass generalizations unless there are believable facts to back them up.  (Note: please exclude this mass generalization from the rule just stated.)

Comment: "*This program is huge or not?*" => No, 2500 lines is an **extremely small** program. As long as *one* person can handle it, it's nowhere big (let alone huge)... I for one am responsible, alone, for about 3 million lines of C++ (not counting helper scripts etc) and I'm not even close to my limit. Now multiply that by a few team-mates...

Comment: Now, aside from the huge/small program issue, I'd be curious to hear **how** `inline` functions "make trouble" in big programs. Care to explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it true?

You can check out the [advantage and disadvantages of Inline Functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/20600/) and justify it