# What is an 'extern inline' function and when to use?

Tags: c++, c++14

There is such thing and it's in the latest C++ draft:

At § 7.1.2 .4:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which
>   it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every
>   case (3.2). [ Note: A call to the inline function may be encountered
>   before its definition appears in the translation unit. — end note ] If
>   the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its
>   first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed. **If a function
>   with external linkage is declared inline in one translation unit, it
>   shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears;
>   no diagnostic is required. An inline function with external linkage
>   shall have the same address in all translation units. A static local
>   variable in an extern inline function always refers to the same
>   object. A type defined within the body of an extern inline function is
>   the same type in every translation unit.**

Some insights on what is this and when to use it?

Comment: Maybe a link-time optimization hint?

Answer (score 5):

`extern` is redundant for functions, so it is pointless to declare a function `extern inline`. If, for example you declared a function `inline` at global scope, the rules of this section would apply. Likewise if you declared a class at global scope and defined a member function within the class definition, as such a function would be *implicitly* `inline`.

The question of when you should declare a function `inline` is a can of worms I'm not inclined to open here. See: [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method)

Comment: `static` might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this draft feature in C++, and whether it made it into a standard. I think it may be borrowing a feature from C.

---

In C (I think C99?), `extern inline` is used in a source file, not a header file. to instruct the tooling that the object file produced from this source should be the one that holds the final implementation. Without it, the linker has to choose a site or duplicate the symbol.

For example, in `my_alloc.h`:

```
inline char *my_alloc(size_t len) { return (char*)malloc(len); }
```

And in `my_alloc.c`:

```
extern inline char *my_alloc(size_t len);
```

Comment: C++ *is* indeed different from C.  You don't need the `extern inline` instantiation (in exactly one compilation unit) in C++.