# Why should I use inline functions when it's up to compiler?

Tags: c++, c

I know how inline functions work, but I've read they are only a suggestion to the compiler, and the compiler may decide to make an inline function non-inline and make a non-inline function inline.  Since compilers know what they are doing far better than I do, why should I even bother making a function inline if the compiler is going to do what it thinks is best?  How much do compilers listen to my "suggestions"?

Comment: The inline keyword increases the chances of a function getting inlined. The reason why `inline` is a suggestion, is that it can often increase the executable size, if the function is too long.

Comment: If you really know what you're doing then you may _force_ compiler to use your _suggestion_. However you may also need to use inline just to put function body in your header file. Note that newest C and C++ differs about this (in particular in which compilation unit the _body_ of inlined function is placed)

Comment: It is essentially pointless these days to use this meaning for the `inline` keyword. Now, it is used almost exclusively as a means to bypass the one-definition rule (ODR). Let the compiler worry about when to (or not to) inline your code.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method

Comment: If you don't provide the code for the inline function to the compiler, it can't inline it — it has to make a function call.  In C, if you have a `static` function then the compiler may (and quite often will) inline it even without the `inline` keyword. If the function is not `static`, it must be created as a referenceable function because code in another file might need to call it.  So, providing the inline function allows the compiler to optimize when otherwise it might not.

Comment: @NathanOliver linked to by far the best answer for this question.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. They differ in this subject. Pick one!