# C++ How to determine if function has capability for being inlined and actually was?

Tags: c++, compilation, inline

I have a question about `inline` functions in C++. I know that similar questions have appeared many times on this. I hope that mine is a little bit different.

I know that when you specify some function to be `inline` it is just a "suggestion" to the compiler. So in case:

```
inline int func1()
{
    return 2;
}
```

> Some code later

```
cout << func1() << endl; // replaced by cout << 2 << endl;
```

So there is no mystery there, but what about cases like this:

```
inline int func1()
{
    return 2;
}

inline int func2()
{
    return func1() * 2;
}

inline int func3()
{
    return func2() * func1() * 2;
}
```

> And so on...

Which of these functions have a chance to become inlined, is it benefitial and how to check what compiler actually did?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method

Comment: You do not need the keyword inline to inline. Simply enable optimization.

Comment: @manni66 ... and make the function's body available in the calling place. Which quite often requires the `inline` keyword.

Comment: This question is asked in a misleading way. The mention of `inline` keyword is irrelevant. The real question is how to determine whether a function is inlined by the complier.

Comment: The C++ inline keyword and compiler optimization inline are only tangentially related.   Make sure not to confuse them.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, a small function with no side-effects is a very good inline canditate and you'll need much more than 2 recursive calls to prevent inlining. You can be pretty sure your `func3()` will be just replaced with 16, regardless of `inline` keyword

Comment: You can see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/RGdBTp) how GCC inlined your functions, and [here](https://godbolt.org/g/XffWYA) how it evaluated the factorial of 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which of these functions have a chance to become inlined

Any and all functions have a chance to become inlined, if the tool<sup>(1)</sup> doing the inlining has access to the function's definition (= body) ...

> is it benefitial

... and deems it beneficial to do so. Nowadays, it's the job of the optimiser to determine where inlining makes sense, and for 99.9% of programs, the best the programmer can do is stay out of the optimiser's way. The remaining few cases are programs like Facebook, where 0.3% of performance loss is a *huge* regression. In such cases, manual tweaking of optimisations (along with profiling, *profiling,* and **profiling**) is the way to go.

> how to check what compiler actually did

By inspecting the generated assembly. Every compiler has a flag to make it output assembly in "human-readable" format instead of (or in addition to) object files in binary form.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Normally, this tool is the compiler and inlining happens as part of the compilation step (turning source code into assembly/object files). That is also the only reason why you may be required to use the `inline` keyword to actually allow a compiler to inline: because the function's definition must be visible in the translation unit (= source file) being compiled, and quite often that means putting the function definition into a header file. Without `inline`, this would then lead to multiple-definition errors if the header file was included in more than one translation unit.

Note that compilation is not the only stage when inlining is possible. When you enable Whole-Program Optimisation (also known as Link-Time Code Generation), one more pass of optimisation happens at link time, once all object files are created. At this point, the `inline` keyword is totally irrelevant, since linking has access to all the function definitions (the binary wouldn't link successfully otherwise). This is therefore *the* way to get the most benefit from inlining without having to think about it at all when writing code. The downside is time: WPO takes time to run, and for large projcts, can prolong link times to unacceptable levels (I've personally experienced a somewhat pathological case where enabling WPO took a program's link time from 7 minutes to 46).

Answer (score 1):

Think of `inline` as only a *hint* to the compiler, a bit like `register` *was* in old versions of C++ and C standards. Caveat, `register` is being obsoleted (in C++17).

> Which of these functions have a chance to become inlined, is it benefitial

**Trust your compiler** on making sane inlining decisions. To enable some particular occurrence of a call, the compiler needs to know the body of the called function. You should not care if the compiler is inlining or not (in theory).

In practice, with the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler:

- [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) is not always improving the performance (e.g. because of [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) issues, [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer), [branch predictor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor), etc etc....)
- inlining decisions depends a *lot* on [optimization options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html). It probably is more likely to happen with `-O3` than with `-O1`; there are many guru options (like `-finline-limit=` and others) to tune it.
- notice that individual calls get inlined or not. It is quite possible that some call occurrence like `foo(x)` at  line 123 is inlined, but another call occurrence (to the *same* function `foo`) like `foo(y)` at some other place like line 456 is not inlined.
- when *debugging*, you may want to disable inlining (because that makes the debugging more convenient). This is possible with the  `-fno-inline` GCC optimization flag (which I often use with `-g`, which asks for debugging information).
- the `always_inline` [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) "forces" inlining, and the `noinline` prevents it.
- if you compile *and link* with *link time optimization* (LTO) such as `-flto -O2` (or `-flto -O3`), e.g. with `CXX=g++ -flto -O2` in your `Makefile`, inlining  can happen between several translation units (e.g. C++ source files). However LTO is at least doubling the compilation time (and often, worse) and consumes memory during compilation (so better have a lot of RAM then), and often improve performance by only a few percents (with weird exceptions to this rule of thumb).
- you might optimize a function differently, e.g. [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html) `#pragma GCC optimize ("-O3")` or with [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) `optimize`
- Look also into [profile-guided optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) with [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) like `-fprofile-generate` and latter optimizations with `-fprofile-use` with other [optimization flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

If you are curious about what calls are inlined (and sometimes, some won't be) look into the generated assembler (e.g. use `g++ -O2 -S -fverbose-asm` and look in the `.s` assembler file), or use some internal [dump options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html).

The observable behavior of your code (except performance) should not depend upon inlining decisions made by your compiler. In other words, don't expect inlining to happen (or not). If your code behave differently with or without some optimization it is likely to be buggy. So read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

See also [MILEPOST](http://ctuning.org/wiki/index.php?title=CTools:MilepostGCC) GCC project (using machine learning techniques for optimization purposes).