# C++ inline optimisation

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

See my example [here](https://godbolt.org/g/KUBSgd) OR
the following c++ & matching assembly

**IMPLICIT INLINE**

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int i) 
{
    return i * i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

    auto value = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::cout << func(value);  


    value = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << func(value);  

    return 1;
}
```

results in

```
func(int):
  imul edi, edi
  mov eax, edi
  ret
main:
  push rbx
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
  mov rbx, rsi
  mov edx, 10
  xor esi, esi
  call strtol
  imul eax, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
  mov esi, eax
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
  mov edx, 10
  xor esi, esi
  call strtol
  imul eax, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
  mov esi, eax
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov eax, 1
  pop rbx
  ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I__Z4funci:
  sub rsp, 8
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
  call std::ios_base::Init::Init()
  mov edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
  mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
  add rsp, 8
  jmp __cxa_atexit
```

**EXPLICIT INLINE**

```
#include <iostream>

inline int func(int i)
{
    return i * i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {

    auto value = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::cout << func(value);  


    value = atoi(argv[2]);
    std::cout << func(value);  

    return 1;
}
```

results in

```
main:
  push rbx
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
  mov rbx, rsi
  mov edx, 10
  xor esi, esi
  call strtol
  imul eax, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
  mov esi, eax
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov rdi, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
  mov edx, 10
  xor esi, esi
  call strtol
  imul eax, eax
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
  mov esi, eax
  call std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(int)
  mov eax, 1
  pop rbx
  ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
  sub rsp, 8
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
  call std::ios_base::Init::Init()
  mov edx, OFFSET FLAT:__dso_handle
  mov esi, OFFSET FLAT:std::__ioinit
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
  add rsp, 8
  jmp __cxa_atexit
```

In the example, if the line 5 is commented out, optimisation of the code inlines the function 'func' at the two call sites, but it leaves the assembly of func in the produced binary. However, if 'func' is explicitly inlined, the function does not exist in the output assembly.

Why does the GCC optimiser leave implicitly inlined functions in the compiled assembly, even though the operations of the inlined function are truly inlined with the calling code?

Comment: post your code here in the question please. If you want our help you should do us the courtesy of making it easy for us.

Comment: What about the assembly? The reason I used Godbolt is because it is very easy to demonstrate what is happening..

Comment: Post code directly in the question. Links to external resources like godbolt are nice extras. There's nothing wrong with posting both a piece of code and a link to it.

Comment: `inline` affects linkage, _not_ optimization. See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/212858). What you're really asking is why functions with global linkage are emitted out-of-line, even if every actual call is inlined. The answer is probably that it's hard to prove, in general, that every call will be inlined. Certainly you can't prove it till after the optimizer runs, and that's ignoring runtime linkers etc. etc.

Comment: @Useless - really?! So if the linker was better at optimising, func wouldn't be included in the final assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The function would go away entirely if it were marked `static`. Because it is not currently marked `static`, it may be referenced by another compilation unit, so it can't be eliminated.