# Unresolved symbol for inline function

Tags: c++, winapi, inline, extern

Please consider the following code:

Test2.h:

```
#ifndef ABCD
#define ABCD

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void Foo();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif // ABCD
```

Test2.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Test2.h"

inline void Foo()
{
}
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Test2.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code I get LNK2019 error (Unresolved external symbol _Foo).
I can solve it in two ways.

1. Remove the inline keyword.
2. Add extern to the function declaration.

Assuming I want this function inline, why do I have to add extern to the declaration?

I use VS2008.

Thanks.

Comment: C or C++? Inline functions are **very** different between the two.

Comment: You could also move the function definition to the header.

Comment: How do you compile and link the code?  What is the link command line?

Comment: `inline` is not the only problem. You declared `extern "C"` function and then define C++ function. Additionally `Foo()` in C equals to `Foo(...)` in C++.

Comment: @S.M. Since `Test2.cpp` includes `Test2.h`, it will see the `extern "C'` declaration, and apply C language linkage to `Foo` correctly, that's not the issue.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `inline` specifier? In C++ it mostly means that the ODR does not apply. But you define `Foo` in the source file, so you do not need to care about ODR in this case anyway.

Comment: As for _inlining_, a compiler cannot inline function, if its definition is not in a translation unit. Which usually means that the definition must be in a header file.

Comment: @DanielLangr The purpose of the inline is exactly what is it - "Replace those function definition wherever those are being called". What you're saying is, moving the definition to the header or using extern in the declaration is the same?

Comment: Why do you use `extern "C"`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why on earth do I deserve a downvote for what you think are irrelevant tags (With all do respect)? I partially agree on the WINAPI because this code is relevant not only for windows but why does C tag is irrelevant?

Comment: Not my downvote.  The code is C++, in C++ source files.  The rules on online functions are different in C and C++.  Using `_tmain()` places you firmly in the world of Windows. It has no meaning anywhere else. We can debate which Windows tagnto use, but it is purely Windows C++ code in the Question; no C code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Got it. Thanks

Comment: @manni66 I need faster execution time for those functions.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir I wish to keep the definitions hidden from the user but still use it as inline for performance. Is that possible by using extern on the function declaration?

Comment: Inline means the programmers using it can see the code. If you don’t want the code exposed, don’t make it inline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Alright, so what's the meaning of adding extern to the function declaration? Does the compiler ignores the inlining?

Comment: Please search on SO (or the wider web) for the information.  There will be answers aplenty for C++ (and for C, but there are differences in detail between the two languages, compounded by differences in the way GCC has handled them historically).

Comment: _I need faster execution time for those functions_ you think `extern "C"` executes faster? That’s bluntly wrong.

Comment: You're right @manni66 I meant faster execution on the inlining. extern "C" is for compiling with C compiler also.

Comment: I don't know what `inline` specifier means in C. In C++, it does not force a compiler to inline function code (C++ compiler may decide not to inline a function marked `inline` and vice versa). See, e.g., this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method. There is also discussion about `extern`.

Comment: Eureka, I finally see what you're trying to achieve. You want a C++ function inlined into C code. I don't think it's possible (correct me if I am wrong). Inlining is _something like_ taking the function body and putting it in the place of a function call. So, effectively, you are placing C++ code into C code. How could a C compiler then compile such a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 Standard Paragraph 3.2.3:

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used.

You have 2 translation units, first made from `Test2.cpp`...:

```
// ... code expanded from including "StdAfx.h"

extern "C" { void Foo(); }

inline void Foo() { }
```

...and second made from `Test.cpp`:

```
// ... code expanded from including "StdAfx.h"

extern "C" { void Foo(); }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

In the second TU, the definition of `Foo` is missing.

Why don't you simply put the definition of `Foo` into the header file? Compiler cannot inline its code if it does not see it.

Comment: Make sense.. I'm still searching for an answer about the extern issue.. I guess I need to dig deeper. Thanks for spending time to help me.

Comment: In C++, the `extern` specifier results in external linkage when used with function declaration. However, function declarations have in most cases external linkage by default, so the `extern` keyword is then superfluous. I am not sure what `extern` means if the function declaration is inside `extern "C"` block.