# Using inline with overloaded operator

Tags: c++

I overloaded operator `<<` for matrix output.

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Tic& b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < b.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.cols; j++)
            os << std::setw(5) << b.board[i][j] << " ";
        os << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Also, I created a small function for printing.

```
inline void print_matrix (const Matrix& _obj)
{
    cout << _obj;
}
```

> Can I use inline for `print_matrix` function?
>
> Will inline be used for overloaded operator, or does the compiler
>   apply this only for `cout` and only then will call `<<` as another
>   function?

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand the meaning of `inline`.

Comment: Perhaps that's why I asked this question:)

Comment: The compiler mostly ignores the keyword for performance purposes. Heuristics have gotten much better over the decades.

Comment: I can use __forceinline if this is required. My question is different. Assuming that the compiler does not ignore inline. Should I use inline for print function in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know if the `inline` in

```
inline void print_matrix (const Matrix& _obj)
{
    cout << _obj;
}
```

also causes the call to `<<` be inlined by the compiler.

The thing is: Your premise is wrong. `inline` was introduced long time ago to control what functions are inlined by the compiler. However, over time it turned out that the compiler is much better at deciding what to inline than humans. As a consequence `inline` became merely a hint to the compiler and its only pratical use case remains to tell the linker that it will find multiple definitions of the function when you use `inline` on a function defined in a header. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more details.

TL;DR: The `inline` above alone does not even tell you whether `print_matrix` gets inlined or not. If you want to know what the compiler really does inline I recommend you this tool: https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 4):

The effects of `inline` is mostly to allow things to be included in several files without creating duplicates. The compiler is required to handle this without causing link errors.

Whether a function is actually inlined or not is controlled by [compiler options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47238hez.aspx), not by the presence of `inline`.

Note that the options go all the way from *"don't inline anything, even if* `inline`" to *"inline whatever seems worthwhile, even if not marked* `inline`".

---

So, you should mark you function `inline` if it is in a header file (and that header might possibly be included in more than one source file).

And the same goes for operators, which are a kind of functions with a funny syntax.