# During what stage of compilation does inline functions in c++ actually expands?

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++, can anyone explain during what stage of the compilation do inline functions get expanded in detail?

Comment: They need to be expanded at linkage stage.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stage"?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ surely its implementation dependant? I'd have thought most compilers would insert the inlined code at compile time?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Since when does _linkage stage_ not count for _"compile time"_?

Comment: Its impossible to tell. All you can know is if the resulting binary is inlined. Most modern compilers ignore the "inline" keywords in terms of actually inlining the function (the compiler is much better at making the decision). It is only required to make sure you don't have double definitions at the linker stage.

Comment: "stage" here reflects the phase of a compiler. (eg: Target code generation).

Comment: There is no "standard compiler architecture". Heck, C++ isn't even required to be compiled as far as I know.

Comment: @user_vavin A compiler might choose to precompile some kind of _assembly template_ for inlined stuff, and insert that later on during linkage stage replacing the correct addresses.

Comment: You seem not to understand what the compiler and linker is doing behind the scenes, this question doesn't exactly make sense.

Comment: I suggest you practice looking things up.  It takes only seconds to find for your review such info as in : https://stackoverflow.com/q/6264249/2785528  or  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases or even http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html.  Lots of opinions and software is remarkably flexible.

Answer (score 2):

When you say "inline" you could be talking about two different things.

In c++ there is the `inline` keyword which is used by the linker. A good explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759575/7480820).

You could also be talking about the compiler optimization, function inlining. Function inlining is done by the optimizer so it is hard to say exactly when it happens. The decision to inline a function could be influenced by the target architecture and it's cache size along with many other things. In general I guess you could say that function inlining is done during optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally at optimisation phase, since there is a sweet synergy with other optimising paths.

For instance, constant propagation. You may infer that your function is called with a particular value rather than an arbitrary argument. Propagating this value inside the function might simplify its body, becoming tight enough to qualify for inlining.

This combined approach is key to get zero-cost abstractions.