# Should I have to implement all 4 operator overload in order to deal with all const and non-const combinations?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

### General context

I have a self-made `struct` and I want to compare two instance of it. In order to do that I obviously overload the `operator==` so I will be able to do so. Now, this operator may be called with 0 to 2 `const` instances and 0 to 2 non-`const` instances.

As I want my operator `==` to compare 2 const as it compare any possible combination of `const` and `non-const`, the best for me should be to write only one overload which can deal with all possible combination. But as far as I know, I didn't find any way to do so.

### Question

Does that mean that if I need to consider all possible combination, I have to write all 4 possible overloads ? Is there anyway I can avoid to write 4 times the same function only with `const` keywords changing ?

---

### Specific example

So here is the `struct`. It represents an object on a plan, and consists of its position and a value associated to it:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int x;
    int y;
    double value;
};
```

Now let's say 2 `Foo` are equal if they have the same value and the same position. I have the following operator:

```cpp
inline bool operator==(Foo object) // Compare two non-const Foo
{
    return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y) && (value == object.value);
}
```

But, eww, unlucky some `Foo` can be constants, meaning that my objects can't move on the plan and can't change their value. And now I need to check if two `const Foo` can be equals and if a non-`const Foo` can be equal to a `const Foo`.

Is there anyway I can do that but still avoid to write those following functions which are almost the same as the first one ?

```cpp
inline bool operator==(const Foo &object) // Compare a non-const Foo with a const Foo
{
    return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y) && (value == object.value);
}

inline bool operator==(const Foo &object) const // Compare two const Foo
{
    return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y) && (value == object.value);
}

inline bool operator==(Foo object) const // Compare a const Foo with a non-const Foo
{
    return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y) && (value == object.value);
}
```

I don't have any requirements on c++ version. It can ever be c++17 or c++20.

Comment: I tried to make this as clear and concise as I could but don't hesitate to ask for any missing info

Comment: I don't see any reason to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a non-`const` `Foo` object, you can use it where `const Foo&` object are expected, and you can call `const`-method on it, so you should only have one overload:

```
bool operator==(Foo const& object) const {
    return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y) && (value == object.value);
}
```

You only needs to differentiate `const` and non-`const` overloads for specific cases where the behavior is different depending if the object is `const` or non-`const`, e.g., for `operator[]`:

```
// You want to return a reference on non-const object and a const-reference
// on const object, so you need both overloads.
X& operator[](std::size_t);
const X& operator[](std::size) const;
```

---

You usually want to have non-member functions for binary operators, with  `friend` if necessary. In your case, since all members are public, you can simply create a free function (outside the `struct`):

```
bool operator==(Foo const& lhs, Foo const& rhs) const {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y && lhs.value == rhs.vallue;
}
```

You can also drop that `inline` modifier which is kind of irrelevant nowadays, see, e.g., [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method).

You can also check [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421708) for some idioms regarding operator overloading.

Comment: Alright, I see. I started by writing the passing-by-value function and got misleaded by the error I got, so I just added the `const reference` one and assumed that I needed all of those I described. Thanks for the precisions on the utility of multiple overloads also

Answer (score 2):

Operator==, like most binary operators, should normally be implemented as a single, non-member, free function:

```
 inline bool operator==(const Foo & a, const Foo & b ) {
       return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y && a.value == b.value;
 }
```

Comment: Which c++ standard allow to do this ? Because I tried this too but it doesn't compile for me. I got a `too many parameters for binary operator 'operator=='` error

Comment: C++ has always allowed (and encouraged) writting functions like this. As I said, you need to make it a non-member function.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do so!

As long as it is just comparison then it is preferred always to use `const references`:

```
  inline bool operator==(const Foo &object)const{
        return (x == object.x) && (y == object.y) && (value == object.value);
  }
```

- The reason is you can pass the address or reference of `const` and `non-const` to a `const` member function but not the contrary.
- There are some cases when overloading depending on `constness` matters.