# The variable access Inline function in C++

Tags: c++, inline

In inline functions, the compiler is suggested to copy a piece of code at compile time into the caller program.

```
#include<iostream>
inline void swap(int *a, int *b){
    a=a^b;
    b=a^b;
    a=a^b;
}
int main(){
    int a=2,b=3;
        swap(a,b);
    std::cout<<a<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the swap function is call by value.
So, suppose that the above code is inlined by the compiler, then will the actual variable `a` and `b` will be passed so that it works perfectly or the part that has an inline function has some other scope?

Because, if it is inlined, the code is directly copied into `main` here, and since no parameter passing will take place, the code have the access to `a` and `b`.

ps:The question has been edited because I was not able to precisely put in words my doubt so it has so may downvotes.

Comment: Notice that `inline` keyword and inlining are unrelated.

Comment: Your swap does xor on pointers. Do instead: inline void swap(int *a, int *b){
    *a=*a^*b;
    *b=*a^*b;
    *a=*a^*b;
}

call as swap(&a, &b).

Comment: While it's not a very good question, I don't understand why it has so many downvotes. There is a misunderstanding, quite natural at that.

Comment: The [inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) does not mean what you think it does. It doesn't *actually* have much (if *anything*) to do with whether code is actually inlined. Rather it is related to the [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

Comment: @dyukha Maybe to get it removed so it does not pop up in the search?

Comment: @0kcats, with this logic I can suggest hundreds questions which should be downvoted, but wasn't.

Comment: `inline void swap(int *a, int *b){
    a=a^b;
    b=a^b;
    a=a^b;
}` - That's just *wrong* and not what you intended. You want to operate on what the pointers *point to*, not the pointer values themselves.

Comment: Recommended reading: [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method)

Comment: "In inline functions, the piece of code at compile time is copied into the caller program." - No. Not correct. It *may* be. But it also *may not*. `inline` has little to do with that.

Comment: "caller program" -- do you mean "calling function"? Because there is only one program being compiled, and the inline function is already part of it by virtue of it being defined. No copying is required.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this XOR approach to swapping is not a good idea. There are too many ways it can go wrong. For example, if you try to swap an integer with itself you end up setting its value to 0.

Comment: your first snippet is wrong. The function takes pointers but you pass `int`s. Once you fix that your manual inlining should be ok

Comment: You should see compiler warnings.  You are passing variables to a function that takes pointers.  Prefix the variables in your function with "p_" or something similar and you should have compiler warnings or errors pop up.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it that the first code fails to work until a pointer to `a` and `b` are used?

Because `swap` takes pointers.  You can't call it without pointers, even it it would be inlined.  The program still needs to be syntactically correct even if the semantics change due to optimizations.

Also note that `inline` is just a suggestion to the compiler to inline the function.  It's actual purpose is to prevent multiple definition errors if you define the function in multiple translation units.

Comment: suppose that the optimization finally inlines the code. Then will it work?

Comment: No, because optimization does not change the meaning of correct code.

Comment: @AdityaGaddhyan Worth noting that even though the function compiles with pointers, it doesn't work. it swaps the pointers around rather than the pointed-at values. Since the pointers are passed by value, there are no observable side effects and the compiler will probably discard the function entirely. Hard to beat the execution time, but not what you want. Consider `void swap(int &a, int &b)` as a replacement.

Comment: @AdityaGaddhyan The code has to be syntactically correct first.  `swap(a,b);` is not correct since `swap` takes pointers.  If you do `swap(&a,&b);` then the code is correct, and the compiler can then choose to instead inline the code instead of calling a function and dealing with pointers.

Comment: @AdityaGaddhyan Your problem has nothing to do with inlining.

Answer (score 0):

*In inline functions, the piece of code at compile time is copied into the caller program.*

That's completely incorrect. Making a function `inline` has no effect on what your program does. If your function does not work without `inline` then it's not going to start working when you make it `inline`, and vice versa.

So the premise of the question is wrong.

Comment: "If your function does not work without inline then it's not going to start working when you make it inline" - It *might*, if the reason it didn't work was that it was violating ODR without the `inline`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `inline` function and usage are wrong.  You are passing variables to a function that requires pointers.

In `main`, your function call should be:
`swap(&a, &b);`

If you don't want to mess with pointers, I recommend a version using *references*:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

inline void my_swap(int& a, int& b)
{
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = a;
}

int main()
{
  int p = 42, q = 1;
  cout << "p: " << p << ", q: " << q << "\n";
  swap(p, q);
  cout << "p: " << p << ", q: " << q << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

The parameters of `swap` are passed by *reference* which means that the function will modify the variables passed to `swap`.

Take the above `main` function and print out the assembly language.  There should be no branch or call instructions to the `swap` function.  Increment the optimization levels as necessary (some compilers won't inline the code at the lowest optimization levels, to make debugging easier).  A very intelligent compiler may replace the entire function with an assembly language instruction for swapping.