# How do I best use #include to prevent my multiple definition error?

Tags: c++, makefile, include, include-guards, multiple-definition-error

While implementing three files (tree.h, tree.cpp, and node.h) into an existing project, I've run into "multiple definition of" errors when trying to reference them in my parser.h and parser.cpp files. I am using include guards to prevent multiple inclusion but I don't think that is doing what I want it to. I am also using plain C++99 and compiling on a Linux machine, I don't have control over that.

The **getNode()** is defined with the **node_t** struct in *node.h* and both need to be available to *parser.cpp, parser.h, tree.cpp, and tree.h*.

```
[user]$ make
g++ -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -o frontend main.o scanner.o parser.o tree.o
scanner.o: In function `getNode(std::string)':
/home/user/Compilers/P2/node.h:21: multiple definition of `getNode(std::string)'
main.o:/home/user/Compilers/P2/node.h:21: first defined here
parser.o: In function `getNode(std::string)':
/home/user/Compilers/P2/node.h:21: multiple definition of `getNode(std::string)'
main.o:/home/user/Compilers/P2/node.h:21: first defined here
tree.o: In function `getNode(std::string)':
/home/user/Compilers/P2/node.h:21: multiple definition of `getNode(std::string)'
main.o:/home/user/Compilers/P2/node.h:21: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [frontend] Error 1
```

Makefile
I tried adding node.h and token.h to the OBJFILES but that only caused those files to be deleted when I did *make clean*

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wno-unused-variable
CXXFLAGS = -g

OBJFILES = main.o scanner.o parser.o tree.o 
TARGET = frontend

all: $(TARGET)


$(TARGET): $(OBJFILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJFILES)


.PHONY: clean
    
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJFILES) $(TARGET) *~
```

node.h

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string>

#include "token.h"

#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

struct node_t
{
    std::string label;
    Token* token1;
    Token* token2;
    //struct node_t *left;
    //struct node_t *right;
    struct node_t *child;
};

node_t* getNode( std::string functionName )
{
    // Create the node
    node_t* node = (struct node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_t)); 
    node->label = functionName;
    node->child = NULL;
    node->token1 = NULL;
    node->token2 = NULL;

    return node;
}

#endif
```

I took all my files and their #include statements and header guards and mocked up a diagram of what all is happening.
[image: visual representation of my files]

Comment: That's hardly a matter of the makefile. Any template class definitions in one of the cpp files?

Comment: To optimise compilation time, move all includes inside the include guard.

Comment: The bug appears to be in `node.h`. My expectation is you have defined a free function named `getNode(std::string)` in the header and multiple translation units are including this header causing a violation of the ODR

Comment: You're going to need to provide a [mre], or at least the code of `node.h`

Comment: Added the content of node.h, how do I go about getting this opened?

Comment: If you put a definition (function or variable, not type) in a header file, **use the `inline` keyword**.  Include guards don't apply when the header is included in multiple compilation units, which is your case.  They just prevent reprocessing the same header many times in a single compilation.

Comment: More detail can be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/103167   It would be pointless to open your question just to mark it as a duplicate of that one.

Comment: Put `node_t* getNode( std::string functionName );` in the header and move the definition to a cpp file.

Comment: `node_t* node = (struct node_t*)malloc(sizeof(struct node_t));` probably should not use `malloc` in `c++`