# how to understand "inline is to indicate that the function may be #included in multiple translation units without causing multiple definition errors."

Tags: c++

"The main use for the inline keyword is not to request inlining, but to indicate that the function may be #included in multiple translation units without causing multiple definition errors."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I write the keyword 'inline' for a function/method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759300/when-should-i-write-the-keyword-inline-for-a-function-method)

Comment: Exactly which part is it that you don't understand?

Comment: "but to indicate that the function may be #included in multiple translation units without causing multiple definition errors." this part, thanks so much! @molbdnilo