# C++ class definition

Tags: c++, class

```
class Rectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area (void) {return (x*y);}
};

void Rectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}
```

I have this class inside of function of another class
its giving error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
could you say me why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a write a function definition inside another function in C++. If anything, you'll need to write the implementation inside your class declaration, like you did with the `area` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should separe your declaration (.h) from your implementation (.cpp). If you want to implement some function in your declaration file (nomally  for simple functions) you should use the **inline reserved word**:

```
Rectangle.h
class Rectangle { 
    int x, y; 
  public: 
    void set_values (int,int); 
    inline int area (void) {return (x*y);} 
}; 

Rectangle.cpp
#include Rectangle.h

void Rectangle::set_values (int a, int b) { 
  x = a; 
  y = b; 
}
```

Comment: I believe your use of "inline" is redundant here; member functions defined within the class body are implicitly inline.

Comment: @Dan:For simple functions like the one mentioned here, inline is the prefered style because of performance. See this question about this matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c

Answer (score 0):

You can make a type in function scope, but you can't declare the function there.  You can do this:

```
class Rectangle { 
   int x, y; 
    public: 
      void set_values (int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
      int area (void) { return (x*y); } 
};
```

But, why not just declare Rectangle normally?  It seems useful enough to want to use in other functions.