# C++ inline if fails in switch

Tags: c++, gcc, switch-statement, inline-if

I just found out the hard way an inline if (A?B:C) does not work as expected in a switch statement.

where A a boolean, B and C both integer unequal to 0. The result of this statement is 0 when placed inside a switch.

I found a stackoverflow post [1] where this behaviour was mentioned but I can not find any explanation why this doesn't work as I would expect. What is causing this?

For example:

```
int foo = 6;

switch(foo)
{
case 6:
  return 10 + true ? 2 : 4;
}
```

[1] [Benefits of inline functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c/146144#146144)

Comment: Please give a code example of what you mean.

Comment: That's called the "conditional operator" or "ternary operator", not "inline if".  The linked discussion is about inline functions, which are not related.  Post some code.

Comment: Do you mean `switch (a?b:c) {...}`?

Comment: int foo = 6;
    switch(foo)
    {
      case 6: return 10 + true?2:4;
    }

Comment: What "doesn't work" about that code?

Comment: The result returned is 2 instead of 12. (fixed typo, was 10)

Comment: It's called operator precedence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `switch`.

```
10 + true ? 2 : 4
```

is equivalent to:

```
(10 + true) ? 2 : 4.
```

If you want it to act like:

```
10 + (true ? 2 : 4)
```

then you will need to write it like that.

Comment: doh! I was wondering why I had so much trouble recreating this in my small example. Thank you!