# inline function definition in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, inline

This a C++ online test question. The test has been done.

```
class Person
{
    std::string name;
    public:
          std::string const &getname(void) const ;      
} ;

inline std::string const &Person::getname() const
{
        return name; 
}
```

A:   The computer inserts the code of the function getname()

B:   The computer generates a call to the function getname()

C:   The default parameter values of the calling function are returned

D:   All arguments of the function are placed on the memory stack

I choose A. Is it correct ?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you accidentally the question.  Also, 3 of the 4 choices are labelled "A".  Which "A" did you choose?

Comment: About A: The compiler *might* make the function inline.

Comment: @AndréCaron I'm assuming he meant the first since the other two values are very likely a typo. Unfortunately, in this case I think it comes down to what your particular compiler wants to do so like all great engineering answers "It depends..."

Comment: I think the answer is "E: `b` and `v`.", but I'm assuming the question was "Which characters appear only once in the following code?", so I could be wrong. It could also be "F: the compiler complains about a missing semicolon before `inline`." if the question was "What will a C++ compiler do with this code?".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Benefits of inline functions in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler *may* inline the function.

The compiler/linker *will not* complain when the function body is found in multiple compilation units, as long as the body is the same.

Answer (score 1):

From the [C++11 draft](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html)

§ 7.1.2\2

> A function declaration (8.3.5, 9.3, 11.3) with an inline specifier
>   declares an inline function. The inline specifier indicates to the
>   implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the
>   point of call **is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism**.
>   An implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution
>   at the point of call; however, even if this inline substitution is
>   omitted, the other rules for inline functions defined by 7.1.2 shall
>   still be respected.

So, as for *requirements*, it's basically just a normal function, so option B.  It might or might not have it's code inserted into the calling function, but that also applies to functions *not* marked inline, and thus isn't really anything to do with the `inline` keyword.