# inline functions in case function is returning something

Tags: inline

If my function is returning some value then making it inline should give error? 
like inline

```
int fun(int x)
{
return x*x)
}
```

is function in main it should open like

```
main()
{
int a=fun(3);// compiler will resolve it as a=return 3*3
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: No, it will resolve it as a normal function call. There's nothing magic about inline functions; the semantics are identical to non-inline functions. Inline functions are *not* the same as macros.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not give any error

probably small functions made inline

for more information [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c)