# What if i use inline function here and there

Tags: c++, inline

I know that inline functions are used so that we can be rid of function calls.

I see that using inline function is a good way of using the storage and keeping the stack more empty.

Is it a good programming practice to use inline functions everywhere.

I think so, because since compilers are not obligated to use inline functions as inline when the functions are complex, so would it be a nice approach to append that little word `inline` to every functions?

Comment: You missed one drawback: the client code has a compile time dependency on the implementation of inline functions. You cannot change the function definition without forcing clients to recompile.

Comment: Since compilers can also make functions inline when they are not declared inline you could just as easily argue that you should never use inline. The important point is that despite appearances the keyword `inline` has nothing to do with whether a function will end up being inlined or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @cipher, yes really, with Microsoft's compiler it's called Whole Program Optimization, it takes place during the link phase, and it can inline functions you haven't declared as inline. I believe g++ has a similar feature.

Comment: @Nawaz : what is it then. can you explain?

Comment: @juanchopanza : Didn't get you. When did we not had our code recompiled after the change of function definition?

Comment: @cipher To understand inline you have to think about when it makes a difference to whether code is legal or not.

Comment: @cipher when the definition is in the implementation, compiled into an object file or library.

Comment: @john Is the *legal* code you are referring to is, "**code which are not too complex to be inline**" ?

Comment: No, it's simpler than that. Put a function without inline in a header file, include that header file in more than one source file and you will get multiple definition errors from the linker. The only true meaning of the inline keyword in C++ is to provide an exception to the One Definition Rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My general rule is to use `inline` functions when the content of the function is less than or equal to the overhead of calling the function.

An example is a *getter* or *setter* method.

After the program works correctly and robustly, I convert some functions in the bottleneck sections to use `inline`.  However, this is a micro-optimization and usually doesn't generate as much savings as redesigning an algorithm.

As others have stated, *inline* functions wreak havoc on the build process because a header file is changed and all dependencies on the header file must be rebuilt.  A non-inlined function would only require building of a single translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

inline is only a hint to the compiler to inline the function. Compilers can also inline other functions you didn't mark as inline when optimizing. The problem with making every function inline, is the whole function will need to be in a header so that it can be called from multiple source files. This will increase compile times. My advice is to forget the inline keyword exists, until you have a real performance issue.