# Inline class method in the header file

Tags: c++, optimization, inline

Is there any differece between the following implementations?

```
class Foo
{
     int bar(int x) const
     { return x * 2; }
};


class Foo
{
     inline int bar(int x) const
     { return x * 2; }
};
```

Comment: No. Member functions defined (with full body) inside the class definition are automatically `inline`. Also note that `inline` is just a *hint* for the compiler, it may or may not actually honor the hint.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So, all template class methods are inline by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Benefits of inline functions in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c)

Comment: You *can* define non-inline member functions of a templated class, but it's not very common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (9.3 Member functions)

> 2 **A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in
>   which case it is an inline member function** (7.1.2), or it may be
>   defined outside of its class definition if it has already been
>   declared but not defined in its class definition.

And

> 3 An inline member function (whether static or non-static) may also be
>   defined outside of its class definition provided either its
>   declaration in the class definition or its definition outside of the
>   class definition declares the function as inline.

Answer (score 0):

When the function is marked as `inline`, it tells the compiler to put the code of the function to the place where the function has been called from. You can have implicit and explicit inlines - member functions of classes are inlined implicitly, so you don't need to type it and in your case there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

7.1.2 Function specifiers

> 3 A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.
>   The inline specifier shall not appear on a block scope function
>   declaration. 94 (**The inline keyword has no effect on the linkage of a function.**) If the inline specifier is used in a friend
>   declaration, that declaration shall be a definition or the function
>   shall have previously been declared inline.

So, no. There is no difference.