# How to "hide" private member function with inline function specifier?

Tags: c++

Having a class, that contains `private` member function, I would like to mark as `inline` (to explicitely mark my intent of hint that particular function may be inlined), but don't expose their implementation to an API consumer. For simplicity, it might look like:

#### `Airplane.h`:

```
class Airplane
{
    char manufacturer[80];
    char mode[80];
    // ... 
public:
    void autopilot_steer_left(int degree);
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    inline bool validate_hydraulic_on_left_wing();  // secret, patent-based, etc.
};
```

#### `Airplane.cpp`:

```
#include "Airplane.h"
// ...

void Airplane::autopilot_steer_left(int degree)
{
    // ...
}
```

Where should I put definition of `Airplane::validate_hydraulic_on_left_wing`? I know that common place is `Airplane.h` (possibly inside class, so it is `inline` implicitely), but this contradicts with my intent.

Comment: Just don't mark it `inline`? See [when should I write the keyword `inline`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/2069064)

Comment: inline isn't doing what you seem to expect ...

Comment: Usually (not necessarily in your case) either the `inline` function is very simple so there is nothing to hide, or it is not simple but it should not be `inline` in this case.

Comment: _"I would like to mark some of them as inline (to explicitely mark my intent of hint that this particular function may be inlined)"_ Don't bother mate

Comment: _"but don't expose their implementation to an API consumer"_ Literally the opposite of what inlining does. This question makes no sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the keyword `inline` in the .cpp file:

```
inline void Airplane::autopilot_steer_left(int degree)
{
    // ...
}
```

Thus your implementation will be hidden in the .cpp file and `inline` as well.

As to the benefits of doing so, however, that is debatable.  Here is a good discussion relating to `inline` performance:
[Benefits of inline functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c)

Comment: @DanielJour - I was just answering his question as to how to have the implementation `inline`, but not in the .h file.

Comment: @DanielJour Maybe the link-time optimization can inline it?

Comment: @KABoissonneault LTO (if available) will probably inline it, though it won't do that based on the presence of the inline keyword, but rather on it's own metrics.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy it's just that inline in the source file won't have the same (presumed, I.e. this was true with compilers before around 2000) effects as when placed in the header file. Back then this would have hinted to inline that function only inside that translation unit, but not in the others, as was the case with inline in the header. Nowadays I'd just write it without inline keyword.

Comment: @DanielJour - I agree.  Doesn't make much sense to use it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

If the function cannot be called from outside of a single translation unit (i.e. cpp file), then there is often no real sense in marking it inline.

From C++ perspective, inline modifier only allows function to be defined in several units. There is no more semantics behind inline keyword.

From perspective of real inlining of function calls (i.e. compiler optimization), it may only be useful if your compiler is configured to never inline functions that are not marked as inline (like [/Ob1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278455(v=vs.60).aspx) for Visual C++). However, it is quite normal for a modern compiler to try to inline all functions it can. In this case the compiler does not even look whether you have marked the function as inline or not: any call within a single unit would be inlined if compiler thinks it makes code better.

Answer (score 3):

This makes no sense. The entire point of inlining functions is to ensure that the definition is available at the callsite to directly replace the call. That is 100% the opposite of what you want to do: to hide the definition away from the callsite.

It doesn't matter anyway, since `inline` is totally ignored for inlining purposes, and is only used to dictate some relaxed linkage requirements. But, as it is, your function is already not going to be inlined, whether you write `inline` on it or not.

**Just remove the `inline` keyword, and define the function externally as you do now.**

Then turn on link-time optimisation and hope your compiler decides to inline the function definition at link-time. That's the very latest you can get the function inlined, and hopefully that's enough "hiding" for your desires.

If not, well, does it *really* matter?