# Calling __host__ __device__ function inside __global__ function causing an overhead

Tags: cuda, gpu

This is the following question from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70796543/creating-multiple-temporary-variable-inside-global-and-device-cuda-funct/70804772?noredirect=1#comment125242735_70804772).
My `__global__` function contains only a single API Geoditic2ECEF(GPS gps). It took 35ms to execute that global function with a single API. However, if I write the entire code of `__host__ __device__ Geoditic2ECEF(GPS gps)` in the `__global__` function rather than calling it as an API, the `__global__` function took only 2 ms to execute. It seems like calling an `__host__ __device__` API inside `__global__` function causing a mysterious overhead.

This is the PTX output when I used the API

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z16cudaCalcDistanceP7RayInfoPK4GPS3PK6float6PK9ObjStatusPKfSB_SB_fiiiiii' for 'sm_52'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z16cudaCalcDistanceP7RayInfoPK4GPS3PK6float6PK9ObjStatusPKfSB_SB_fiiiiii     0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads 
ptxas info    : Used 9 registers, 404 bytes cmem[0]
```

This is the PTX output when I dont use the API

```
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z16cudaCalcDistanceP7RayInfoPK4GPS3PK6float6PK9ObjStatusPKfSB_SB_fiiiiii' for 'sm_52' 
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z16cudaCalcDistanceP7RayInfoPK4GPS3PK6float6PK9ObjStatusPKfSB_SB_fiiiiii     0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads 
ptxas info    : Used 2 registers, 404 bytes cmem[0]
```

The only difference is that the API version used 9 registers while the non-API version used 2 registers. What can I deduce from this information.

In file `utils.cu`, I defined following structs and API

```
struct GPS {
    float latitude;
    float longtitude;
    float height;
};
```

```
struct Coordinate
{
    __host__ __device__ Coordinate(float x_ = 0, float y_ = 0, float z_= 0)
    {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
        z = z_;
    }
    __host__ __device__ float norm()
    {
        return sqrtf(x * x + y * y + z * z);
    }

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

```
__host__ __device__ Coordinate Geoditic2ECEF(GPS gps)
{
    Coordinate result;

    float a = 6378137;
    float b = 6356752;
    float f = (a - b) / a;
    float e_sq = f * (2 - f);

    float lambda = gps.latitude / 180 * M_PI;
    float phi = gps.longtitude / 180 * M_PI;

    float N = a / sqrtf(1 - e_sq * sinf(lambda) * sinf(lambda));
    result.x = (gps.height + N) * cosf(lambda) * cosf(phi);
    result.y = (gps.height + N) * cosf(lambda) * sinf(phi);
    result.z = (gps.height + (1 - e_sq) * N) * sinf(lambda);
    return result;
}
```

In `main.cu`, I have following functions

```
__global__ void cudaCalcDistance(GPS* missile_cur,
                                 int num_faces, int num_partialPix)
{
    int partialPixIdx = threadIdx.x + IMUL(blockIdx.x, blockDim.x);
    int faceIdx = threadIdx.y + IMUL(blockIdx.y, blockDim.y);

    if(faceIdx < num_faces && partialPixIdx < num_partialPix)
    {
        Coordinate missile_pos;
        // API version
        missile_pos = Geoditic2ECEF(missile_cur->gps);
        // non_API version
//        float a = 6378137;
//        float b = 6356752;
//        float f = (a - b) / a;
//        float e_sq = f * (2 - f);

//        float lambda = missile_cur->latitude / 180 * M_PI;
//        float phi = missile_cur->longtitude / 180 * M_PI;

//        float N = a / sqrtf(1 - e_sq * sinf(lambda) * sinf(lambda));
//        missile_pos.x = (missile_cur->height + N) * cosf(lambda) * cosf(phi);
//        missile_pos.y = (missile_cur->height + N) * cosf(lambda) * sinf(phi);
//        missile_pos.z = (missile_cur->height + (1 - e_sq) * N) * sinf(lambda);

    }
}
```

```
void calcDistance(GPS * data)
{
    int num_partialPix = 10000;
    int num_surfaces = 4000;


    dim3 blockDim(16, 16);
    dim3 gridDim(ceil((float)num_partialPix / threadsPerBlock),
                 ceil((float)num_surfaces / threadsPerBlock));

    cudaCalcDistance<<<gridDim, blockDim>>>(data,                                 
                             m_Rb2c_cur,num_surfaces,num_partialPix);
    gpuErrChk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

int main()
{
    GPS data(11, 120, 32);
    GPS *d_data;
    gpuErrChk(cudaMallocManaged((void**)&d_data, sizeof(GPS)));
    gpuErrChk(cudaMemcpy(d_data, &data, sizeof(GPS), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    calcDistance(d_data);
    gpuErrChk(cudaFree(d_data));
}
```

Comment: Could you provide compilable code? Without it it will be difficult to see what the compiler does with your two versions.

Comment: I updated my post. I think I found the real culprit here. The context is that my API function Geoditic2ECEF defined in file utils.cu and my __global__ function is defined in a different file, the so-called main.cu. Maybe this results in the situation when executing the global function, multiple threads have to find and access the address of the API function. I think it is some kind of data race. I tried to make the __device__ API inline by using the keyword __forceinline__ but it fails to link device code –

Comment: The current kernel will be optimized to an empty kernel.

Comment: Device functions from different files cannot be inlined. This introduces overhead. With a recent compiler, you could try to use link-time optimization. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#optimization-of-separate-compilation

Comment: I did use the flag -rdc=true. Is that what you are referring to ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't seem to have asked a question that I can see, so I will assume your question is something like "what is this mysterious overhead and what are my options to mitigate it?"

When the call to a `__device__` function is in a different compilation unit than the definition of that function, the compiler cannot [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34046227/does-calling-device-functions-impact-the-number-of-registers-used-in-cuda/34046510#34046510) that function (generally).

This can have a variety of performance impacts:

- The call instruction creates some overhead
- the function call has an ABI that reserves registers, this creates register pressure which may affect code performance
- the compiler may have to transfer additional function parameters outside of registers, via the stack.  This adds additional overhead.
- The compiler cannot (generally) optimize across the function call boundary.

All of these can create performance impacts to varying degrees, and you can find other questions here on the `cuda` tag which mention these.

The most common solutions I know of are:

1. Move the definition of the function to the same compilation unit as the calling environment (and, if possible, remove `-rdc=true` or `-dc` from compilation command line).
2. In recent CUDA versions, make use of [link-time optimization](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/improving-gpu-app-performance-with-cuda-11-2-device-lto/).

Comment: I chose your first solution and it solves the problem. Thank you very much