# Kotlin - when expression with return type of function

Tags: android, function, generics, types, kotlin

I want to take advantage of kotlin's when expressions and generic methods to simplify shared preferences api of Android.

Instead of calling  getString() & getInt() etc. all the time, What I want to do is to create an extension function that would switch based on return type of function and call appropriate method. Something like below :

```
  fun <T> SharedPreferences.get(key: String): T? {
        when (T) { //how do I switch on return type and call appropriate function?
            is String -> getString(key, null)
            is Int -> getInt(key, -1)
            is Boolean -> getBoolean(key, false)
            is Float -> getFloat(key, -1f)
            is Long -> getLong(key, -1)
        }
        return null
    }
```

Of Course, it will not work. But is there any solution to use when expression for return type of a function? All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To achieve exactly what you want, you can use [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters). This will make the compiler inline your function at its call sites with `T` replaced with the type used at the call site.

The function would look like:

```
@Suppress("IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_ANY")
inline operator fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.get(key: String): T? =
    when (T::class) {
        String::class -> getString(key, null)
        Int::class -> getInt(key, -1)
        Boolean::class -> getBoolean(key, false)
        Float::class -> getFloat(key, -1f)
        Long::class -> getLong(key, -1)
        else -> null
    } as T?
```

<sup>If you make `get` an [`operator` function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#binary-operations), you can also call it using the operator syntax: `prefs[name]`.</sup>

The calls should, of course, provide enough type information for the compiler to infer `T`:

```
val i: Int? = prefs["i"] // OK, the type information is taken from the declaration
val j: Int = prefs["i"]!! // OK

val x = prefs["x"] // Error, not enough type information
val y = prefs.get<String>("y") // OK, the type will be `String?`

fun f(z: Int) = z
f(prefs["z"]!!) // OK, the type information is taken from the parameter type
```

Comment: interesting...thanks. But "This will make the compiler inline your function". Can you explain me what does inlining actaully do. I read the docs but it shows that inlining is associated with something different like [performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/145841/3830694). I am not an expert. Can you explain in simple terms what does inline actually do?

Comment: @KrupalShah, in Kotlin, [`inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) are indeed not intended to be a performance tool because JVM itself manages functions inlining at runtime good enough. Instead, `inline` functions are used for flexibility. The two major use cases are [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) and [non-local control flow](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) (`break` and `continue` might be added to `return` in future).

Comment: @KrupalShah, note that both use cases require the function body to be transformed (for reified generics, the type parameter is replaced with the type present at call site, because otherwise the type parameter would be [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), and the code could not use it; for control flow, the functional argument is inlined, so that `return` inside it would work with the outer function). These transformations are done for each of the function calls, and the transformed code is then inlined at the call sites.

Comment: Good solution, but it might be better only to get the class of T in the inline function, and extract the rest of the body to another non-inline function in order to minimize amount of code inlined at the call site.