# Extreme slow-down when starting at second permutation

Tags: c++, performance, function, permutation, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v(12);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

    //std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end());

    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    clock c;
    auto start = c.now();

    unsigned long counter = 0;
    do {
        ++counter;
    } while (std::next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end()));

    auto end = c.now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start);    
    std::cout << counter << " permutations took " << duration.count() / 1000.0f << " s";
}
```

Compiled with GCC (MinGW) 5.3 `-O2` on my AMD 4.1 GHz CPU this takes `2.3 s`. However if I comment in the uncommented line it slows down to `3.4 s`. I would expect a minimal speed-up because we measure the time for one permutation less. With `-O3` the difference is less extreme `2.0 s` to `2.4 s`.

Can anyone explain that? Could a super-smart compiler detect that I want to traverse all permutations and optmize this code?

Comment: Calling `next_permutation` twice caused it to not be inlined

Comment: Do you see a similar behavior with -O0?

Comment: Fwiw, Compiler Explorer clearly shows the lack of inlining in -O2 - see [commented code](https://godbolt.org/g/RJQ3cJ) and [uncommented code](https://godbolt.org/g/6ZVA31). The weirder case is actually with -O3, in which all calls are inlined but the assembly is arranged slightly differently. Why the reorder produces worse performance (according to the OP's report) is unclear.

Comment: @Serge no with -O0 both run equally slow

Comment: Thanks, i find it  educational. BTW, i see no difference whatsoever with -O3. Actually the 'slow' version runs a fraction of a second faster than the fast one :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the compiler gets confused by you calling the function in two separate lines in your code, causing it not be inline.

GCC 8.0.0 also behaves as yours.

[Benefits of inline functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c) It provides a simple mechanism for the compiler to apply more optimizations, so losing the inline identification may cause a severe drop of performance, in some cases.

Comment: That seems to be indeed a part of the problem: Putting the line into a non-optimizable but always false `if` statement leads to the same drop although the function is never called. Got spot. _But_ the code runs still `0.1 s` slower if the function is executed.