# Can the inline keyword change a function's behaviour.

Tags: c++, inline

I have a poorly designed library that has implementations of non-`inline` functions in a header file.

My project which has to use the library relies on it, but it produces duplicate definitions of all the non-`inline`functions in the header file upon linking.

An easy fix is to declare the functions `inline` and compile as usual, an even better fix is to move the implementation files to their own `.cpp` files and compile the rest as a library.

So my question is twofold: 
1) If I declare the functions inline, will it affect their behaviour, i.e. is it possible that a name collision might not be occuring normally but will after I declare the functions inline. e.g. can it make them not-thread-safe. 
2) (Optional) Is there a textbook or a detailed guide to compiling dynamically linked  libraries under Linux/OS X.

Comment: Related: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1759300/3871028) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/145838/3871028)

Comment: Reminder:  the `inline` keyword is a suggestion to the compiler.  The compiler may ignore it when higher optimizations are selected.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, so it should preserve the exact behaviour of the function, or am I wrong.

Comment: It will preserve functional behavior as far as the C++ standard.  You may lose some debug ability to detect call/return behavior.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The `inline` is not as much for the compiler as it is a linker keyword!