# Cython Compiled EXE needs Python Installation to RUN

Tags: python, gcc, compilation, runtime, cython

I have compiled my python code (in Windows) with the following cython and gcc commands:-

```
cython --embed -o hello.c hello.py
gcc -municode -mthreads -Wall -O -IC:\Python37\include -LC:\Python37\libs hello.c -lpython37 -Wl,--subsystem,windows -o hello.exe
```

(I am using modules such as request, pysimpleguiqt and fdb in hello.py)

The resulting exe requires python installation to execute. Is there any way to compile it without the need of python installation at runtime?

Comment: Did you consider installing some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your computer? It would make development technically simpler, but the legal issues remain

Comment: What software license and copyright does your code has?

Comment: What is your code doing, and where does it execute (on which device, which country) ?

Comment: Very close to a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959902/make-executable-file-from-multiple-pyx-files-using-cython. You can't do this with Cython (or if you could it's very very difficult).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any way to compile it without the need of python installation at runtime?

Perhaps *technically* yes (with some your improvements to Cython) but then ....

### the resulting executable *might* be illegal to redistribute

(if you use static linking and did *not* get legally proper software licenses)

**Read carefully again all [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) licenses involved with Python and all your dependencies, even indirect ones** and show them (with the [EULA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) governing your Windows system) to your lawyer.

If you are coding something in a professional setting, consider coding it in some other language than Python.  Be aware of [tivoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tivoization).

### I am not a lawyer

**Consult your lawyer for [software license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_license) issues.** The topic is *really* complex and requires help from a professional lawyer, especially for [executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) that are shipped worldwide or [embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) in some device. **Software related laws are different in the USA and in France** (and probably even in various states of the USA) **or in India or China**.

> The resulting exe requires python installation to execute

That is expected and normal. Related topic is called [DLL hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).

> (I am using modules such as request, pysimpleguiqt and fdb in hello.py)

[PySimpleGuiQt](https://pypi.org/project/PySimpleGUIQt/) is depending upon [Qt](https://qt.io/). So **you'll need a [Qt license](https://www.qt.io/licensing/) for Windows**, if you want to legally distribute the resulting executable (if your code is embedded, you'll need a Qt license for the embedded system). [fdb](https://pypi.org/project/fdb/) has a different license.

See also https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

You could also (with prior approval from your manager or client) release and distribute your software under [GPLv3+](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) and have your lawyer check that all software licenses are compatible and legal...

You might recode a Python bytecode interpreter using your own [JIT compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries. This should take at least months and the resulting executable might be legal (if you bought a Qt license at least).

### you need a lawyer

PS. I am personally member of [APRIL](https://www.april.org/en/), a French non-profit association promoting open source software. Even in France, the legal topic is *really* difficult. If your employer or client is selling your software (with license violation) in France, I expect APRIL to go to court against your product. Legal precedents are favorable (unless of course a proper Qt license has been bought). Some legal cases went to [Court of Cassation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Court_of_Cassation_(France)), and APRIL won.

NB. I professionally wrote some research grants proposals related to rewriting Cython like suggested above. As often, the legal issues are the most difficult to write about. That grant was not funded. See for example [Systematic competitiveness cluster](https://systematic-paris-region.org/en/). They wrote in French a document about licensing issues in French law.