# How to transfer file from Ubuntu to Windows using Python

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, ubuntu, file-transfer

I'm trying to perform automation for transferring the file from  Ubuntu(Linux) to Window system using python. I'm stuck with how I can implement this. Can anyone please suggest me a way to implement this.
My input for this will username, password, and windows path for the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't explain what *transfer files* mean, and if you want to transfer on the same computer (having a Windows file system and a Linux one on two different disk partitions) or on two different ones. You should think in terms of network [communication protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol) and [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system).

For remote file transfer,  think in terms of network [communication protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol) : you might consider using [rcp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp) or [scp](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm) or [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) or [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) or to transfer the files (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/160388/64680) and [that](https://tylercipriani.com/blog/2017/07/09/the-rsync-algorithm-in-python/)). Take into account [cybersecurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_security) considerations, so consider Python [cryptographic services](https://docs.python.org/3/library/crypto.html).  You could also consider network file systems such as [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [CIFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) (a.k.a. SMB) or [sshfs](https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs). HTTP and HTTPS and SSH protocols (both client and server side, look also into [libssh](https://www.libssh.org/)) which is widely supported by Python or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) bindings.

For local computer transfer between different disk partitions, think in terms of [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system), you could consider mounting the other's OS partition. Be then aware of [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT) or [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) and CIFS support in Linux, and  [Ext2fs](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) and NFS support on Windows.

You can code in [Python](https://python.org/) (with [pycurl](https://pypi.org/project/pycurl/) and/or other [Internet protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/internet.html)) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) quite easily [web services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). Be aware of [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) and [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) (and [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol) to send emails). You could be interested by [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) to code a nice web interface. You may be interested by Python or Guile bindings to SMTP client libraries, HTTPS or `libssh` server or client libraries.

Consider also using [distributed version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control) systems such as [git](https://git-scm.com/) - with a remote repository. Of course you'll find [pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2), a Python binding to it, and of course `git` is running both server side and client side on both Windows and Linux.

Be also aware of legal licensing considerations mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61927867/841108).

Comment: File transfer on the same computer having a windows file system and a Linux one on two different disk partitions (Dual booted)

Comment: Can we use Python for this

Comment: Yes. Python is binding lots of other libraries.

Comment: Do you have any sample implementation for reference

Comment: My source will be Linux & Destination will be window then which can I choose

Comment: Can I use SMB for this

Comment: SMB is called CIFS, mentioned in my answer

Comment: Among NFS, CIFS, sshfs, and libssh what should be better matched with python

Comment: I don't understand that question, and "better" is strongly a matter of opinion.

Comment: Can we move this to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214396/discussion-between-edward-arrow-and-basile-starynkevitch).